# How to make Xvfb display visible?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I am running selenium through Xvfb on display number :99 like this:

> /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 & export DISPLAY=":99" &&
>   java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar
>   -port 4444

However display with number other than :0 is not visible by default. How do I make it visible to actually see what selenium is doing in the browser?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's virtual.  From the man page `Xvfb(1)`:

> Xvfb is an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware and no physical input devices.  It emulates a dumb framebuffer using virtual memory.

Also in the man page:

> `Xvfb -pixdepths 3 27 -fbdir /var/tmp`
>     The server will listen for connections as server number 0, will have the default screen configuration (one screen, 1280x1024x8), will also support pixmap depths of 3 and 27,  and  will  use
>     memory mapped files in /var/tmp for the framebuffer.
>
> `xwud -in /var/tmp/Xvfb_screen0`
>     Displays screen 0 of the server started by the preceding example.

Comment: xwud is like a screenshot utility for virtual screens, right?

Comment: `xwud` is the undumper, `xwd` (X Window dump) is a generic screenshot utility for any X screen/disaply.  The special thing about Xvfb though is that its contents are already `xwd` dump files (if you say so, via `-fbdir` that is).

Comment: @Nav Xvfb is a framebuffer in RAM, and no, there is no latency.

Answer (score 76):

### Use [X11vnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc)

All you need is to install `x11vnc` via:

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc xvfb fluxbox
```

<sup>Optionally install fluxbox to have simple window manager.</sup>

#### Run `x11vnc` in shell

Then to setup access to Xvfb for remote control, you can use X11 over SSH or VNC over SSH, e.g.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
fluxbox &
x11vnc -display $DISPLAY -bg -forever -nopw -quiet -listen localhost -xkb
```

#### Run `x11vnc` using script

Here is script friendly version to run `Xvfb`, `x11vnc` and `fluxbox`:

```
export DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0} # Select screen 0 by default.
xdpyinfo
if which x11vnc &>/dev/null; then
  ! pgrep -a x11vnc && x11vnc -bg -forever -nopw -quiet -display WAIT$DISPLAY &
fi
! pgrep -a Xvfb && Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
sleep 1
if which fluxbox &>/dev/null; then
  ! pgrep -a fluxbox && fluxbox 2>/dev/null &
fi
echo "IP: $(hostname -I) ($(hostname))"
```

<sup>Note: I'm using it in the following [Docker project](https://github.com/EA31337/EA-Tester) (check `.funcs.cmds.inc.sh`).</sup>

#### Run `x11vnc` using one-liner

Or you can use the following one-liner:

```
$ x11vnc -create -env FD_PROG=/usr/bin/fluxbox \
    -env X11VNC_FINDDISPLAY_ALWAYS_FAILS=1 \
        -env X11VNC_CREATE_GEOM=${1:-1024x768x16} \
        -gone 'killall Xvfb' \
        -bg -nopw
```

---

- `-create` makes it start Xvfb
- `X11VNC_FINDDISPLAY_ALWAYS_FAILS=1` makes it goto the created Xvfb session (Display `:1` rather than `:0` which will be normal desktop)
- `FD_PROG=/usr/bin/fluxbox` makes it fire up Fluxbox (Ubuntu's one, should have background Ubuntu logo)
- `X11VNC_CREATE_GEOM=${1:-1024x768x16}` sets screen to 16bit colour 1024x768
- `-gone` cleans up when it exits as otherwise Xvfb is left behind (killing `xvfb` also kills `fluxbox`)

### Connect to Xvfb which runs in the Docker container

If you need to connect to Xvfb which runs on Docker container, it's a bit more complicated. You can ssh to your Docker container
Here are the steps:

Install and run all dependencies inside the Docker container:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt update && apt -qqq install x11vnc xvfb fluxbox openssh-server net-tools
export DISPLAY=:0
# Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
x11vnc -display $DISPLAY -bg -forever -nopw -quiet -listen localhost -xkb
fluxbox 2>/dev/null &
mkdir -v /run/sshd ~/.ssh
/usr/sbin/sshd &
echo ssh-TYPE YOUR_PUBKEY_HERE | tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys # Get it from 'ssh-add -L' on your host
```

Now, on the host, ssh to the container with a local tunnel:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 root@172.17.0.2
```

<sup>Where `172.17.0.2` is your container IP. To check the IP of the container, run `ip addr` or `ifconfig`</sup>

For further details, check below.

#### Connect to VNC on remote

If your Xvfb listen on localhost only, you can setup tunneling to localhost, so a vncviewer can then connect to localhost to get remote control over the server. E.g.

```
ssh -N -T -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@remotehost &
vncviewer -encodings 'copyrect tight zrle hextile' localhost:5900
```

Or to listen on all addresses with password, use:

```
x11vnc -display :0.0 -usepw
```

<sup>To setup password, run: `x11vnc -storepasswd`.</sup>

Finally, use VNC client to connect to `localhost:5900` on your local host.

See: [Remote control over SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#Remote_control_over_SSH) at Xvfb Wikipedia page

---

Check also:

- [Using VNCserver + GUI application + Virtual Display in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36221215/55075)
- [Ubuntu Fluxbox GUI with x11vnc and Xvfb](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Fluxbox_GUI_with_x11vnc_and_Xvfb)

Comment: This should be the preferred answer as it is well rounded. Covers all aspects of connecting to your frame buffer locally, via a tunnel and remotely. Thank you @kenorb

Answer (score 35):

You can get a live view by running a VNC server against the Xvfb display, like this:

```
x11vnc -display :99 -localhost &
vncviewer :0
```

Comment: If im running Selenium + x11vnc on a Jenkins node, is there anyway I can remotely view what’s occurring? Would I run vncviewer locally & point it to the Jenkins node?

Comment: @MikeR in principle, yes, but the `-localhost` argument means that x11vnc is only accessible from localhost, so you would probably need different arguments to `x11vnc`, and perhaps an open firewall port. Alternatively, you could set up a proxy for VNC's port, eg ssh tunnel.

Comment: @seanf I see a black screen instead of the browser. Can you please have a look at this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935935/xvfb-on-jenkins-connecting-to-wrong-display-display-shows-black-screen

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is also to constantly take screenshots of the program like this:

```
while /bin/true; do
    DISPLAY=:99 import -window root ~/Pictures/xvfb_screenshot.png
    sleep 0.1
done &
PID=$!
feh --reload 0.1 ~/Pictures/xvfb_screenshot.png 2>/dev/null
kill $PID
```

Note: requires to install *imagemagick* and *feh*