# Is it possible to have GUI for docker container?

Tags: user-interface, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I want to have separate environment for my developers in their system so that I can still protect their system from any hardware/software failure due to the crash by their program. What I want is A system should have container, whenever developer login into their system they should again login into the container to start their work It's like guest/standard user of system, but it should work with container. So the container should give an environment like real system(GUI). Is it possible with docker? I know about run a specify application from container with GUI as [can you run GUI apps in a docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker). But in my case get developers environment(with GUI) with docker for example login into docker container with VNC client as

```
-----------------------------------------------
| real system (VNC client)     | docker   |   |
|             ---------->      |container |   |
|                              |          |   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Checkout http://dockerfile.github.io/#/ubuntu-desktop, this basically setup a VNC server for you to remote connect to your system in docker with a VNC client. You will to customize it by yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker for GUI-based environments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095968/docker-for-gui-based-environments)