# GUI Qt Application in a docker container

Tags: qt, docker

I try to run some Qt application in a docker container by mounting `/tmp/.X11-unix`. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095968/docker-for-gui-based-environments)  that can be difficult.

So when I run kdevelop in a docker container, it does not work (I get an empty window). But if I run qtcreator it's fine.

I think the difference is because of the Qt version used (kdevelop is developed with Qt4 and qtcreator with Qt5). All my other Qt5 applications work fine, but not a single Qt4 application.

**Question:**

Does anyone know what to do to launch a Qt4 application, without going a long way round like with vnc or ssh, just like this:

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix someQt4AppContainer
```

?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qt5 and Qt4 has a different rendering subsystems

Qt4 renderer just needs a hint:

```
export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM="native"
```

This must be work

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM="native" docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix someQt4AppContainer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's work fine. But you have to export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM="native" in the container. And you can run application qt4 and qt5 as well.

Comment: I had to do both this and set QT_X11_NO_MITSHM as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989420/543720

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen`

This will make the shell variable visible to programs invoked from this shell.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm getting this error `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "offscreen" in ""` when attempting to run openscad