# Qt5 Docker GUI occasionally rendering dropdown lists as noise

Tags: docker, qt5

In two completely independently developed projects (a PyQt application at work, not developed by me, and a C++ Qt application I'm working on as a side project), I'm seeing dropdown rendering errors. First, here's what the render error looks like:

Docker QT Rendering Error

[image]

Both applications run in Docker (with your typical X11 socket volume-mount for GUI passthru), both rendering errors present identically and only periodically. My side project (the one in the image) seems to always present the error the first time I start my program after I start the Docker container, but each time after that, the list renders correctly. For the work application (which is more complex than what I have pictured here), the dropdown list that doesn't get rendered correctly changes often and seems to sometimes be triggered by resizing/maximizing the window, but isn't repeatable.

I'm running on qtdeclarative5-dev on Ubuntu 18. The work application is running on PyQt5 from PyPI.

This problem is likely related to the question here [Qt app UI elements randomly rendered as blank/black in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501594/qt-app-ui-elements-randomly-rendered-as-blank-black-in-docker) but that question went unanswered unfortunately.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I've posted an alternative workaround for not displaying those errors in the original question you mention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56080718/11285478