# Gtk cannot display window while using docker

Tags: windows, docker, gtk, x11, gtk2

I am making an app that uses Tensorflow and OpenCV on Windows. Because of tensorflow, I am using Docker. I initially ran my docker container with the command

```
docker run -it -v $HOME/Documents/tensorflowSource:/tensorflowSource -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/temp.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

following the answer to a similar question here: [Docker for GUI-based environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095968/docker-for-gui-based-environments)

On running my program (which should open a window and effectively streams a video), I am given the following error

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: unixneeds-to-be-defined
```

I am sort of lost at this point, what can I do to display the Gtk window my program wants to display? Any solution would be nice, even if it doesn't involve showing the window from the docker container

Comment: The commands you're trying to run (with /tmp/.X11-unix and DISPLAY) assume you are running everything on a linux system. You don't have an X-Windows server to connect to on MS Windows, it's a completely different GUI system.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch, makes sense. Would you have any idea how to show the  display from my docker anyway?

Comment: Short of running a Linux GUI on your docker host, the options get limited. You can probably setup a vnc server on the Linux side, display the container to that, and connect to that server from Windows.