# Access host XServer from Docker container

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, docker, xserver, mesa

My application running inside Docker container uses OpenGL for off-screen rendering.

If the container is running on host with graphics environment, it should use host's XServer for rendering.

I set up such container and it works perfectly on any system with mesa drivers installed (softpipe or nouveau) but does not work on a system with NVidia proprietary drivers.

How can I create docker container that is capable of hardware accelerated rendering (where possible) but is completely independent of actual graphics hardware installed in the system?
Or I need different versions of containers for each graphics environment I may encounter?

Comment: For now I end up with Xvfb solution that works on all systems. It turns out that you probably need different containers for each hardware environment if you want to use hw rendering.

Comment: Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container/25168483#25168483) -- the answers by @AryehLeibTaurog and Jürgen Weigert set up a genuine connection from docker container to host Xserver.