# Installing GNOME Desktop on Centos 7 minimal : Docker image

Tags: docker, gnome, centos7

I have installed GNOME Desktop in Centos 7 minimal Docker image using the following command. 
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools" .

I enabled the GUI Instance by:
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target

I am unable to access the GUI mode. Can anyone guide how to do it?

Comment: You need a valid display, check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try echo $DISPLAY to see the installed GUI 
visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/432610/how-to-know-which-processes-have-the-display-variable-set

Answer (score 0):

the best explanation I have seen on that subject is this post https://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/running-a-gui-application-in-a-docker-container/