# run apps using audio in a docker container

Tags: qt, audio, docker, alsa, pulseaudio

This question is inspired by [Can you run GUI apps in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753).

The basic idea is to run apps with audio and ui (vlc, firefox, skype, ...)

I was searching for docker containers using pulseaudio but all containers I found where using pulseaudio streaming over tcp.
(security sandboxing of the applications)

- https://gist.github.com/hybris42/ce429de428e5af3a344a
- https://github.com/jlund/docker-chrome-pulseaudio
- https://github.com/tomparys/docker-skype-pulseaudio

In my case I would prefere playing audio from an app inside the container directly to my host pulseaudio. (without ssh tunneling and bloated docker images)

Pulseaudio because my qt app is using it ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

it took me some time until i found out what is needed. (Ubuntu)

we start with the docker run command `docker run -ti --rm myContainer sh -c "echo run something"`

ALSA:
we need `/dev/snd` and some hardware access as it looks like.
when we put this together we have

```
docker run -ti --rm \
    -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd \
    --lxc-conf='lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 116:* rwm' \
    myContainer sh -c "echo run something"`
```

In new docker versions without lxc flags you shoud use this:

```
docker run -ti --rm \
    -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd \
     --privileged \
    myContainer sh -c "echo run something"`
```

PULSEAUDIO:
update: it may be enought to mount the pulseaudio socket within the container using -v option. this depends on your version and prefered access method. see other answers for the socket method.

Here we need basically `/dev/shm`, `/etc/machine-id` and `/run/user/$uid/pulse`. But that is not all (maybe because of Ubuntu and how they did it in the past). The envirorment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` has to be the same in the host system and in your docker container. You may also need `/var/lib/dbus` because some apps are accessing the machine id from here (may only containing a symbolic link to the 'real' machine id). And at least you may need the hidden home folder `~/.pulse` for some temp data (i am not sure about this).

```
docker run -ti --rm \
    -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm \
    -v /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id \
    -v /run/user/$uid/pulse:/run/user/$uid/pulse \
    -v /var/lib/dbus:/var/lib/dbus \
    -v ~/.pulse:/home/$dockerUsername/.pulse \
    myContainer sh -c "echo run something"
```

In new docker versions you might need to add `--privileged`.
Of course you can combine both together and use it together with `xServer` ui forwarding like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971413/2835523

Just to mention:

- you can handle most of this (all without the used id) in the `dockerfile`
- using `uid=$(id -u)` to get the user id and gid with `id -g`
- creating a docker user with this id

create user script:

```
mkdir -p /home/$dockerUsername && \
echo "$dockerUsername:x:${uid}:${gid}:$dockerUsername,,,:/home/$dockerUsername:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
echo "$dockerUsername:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
mkdir /etc/sudoers.d && \
echo "$dockerUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$dockerUsername && \
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$dockerUsername && \
chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/$dockerUsername
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the --lxc-conf option was removed in 2014.  https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5797

Comment: I have not tested it but I guess there are replacements for the parameter. --privileged, --cap-add, -cgroup-parent and --device could work

Comment: -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd --privileged works! Check: https://github.com/pwasiewi/docker-freeciv-client

Comment: The ALSA method doesn't work for me. I get the following error `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`.

Comment: Are the snd modules loaded (lsmod | grep snd)? What are your cards (cat /proc/asound/cards)? Is your user in audio group (grep "^audio" /etc/group | grep "$USER")? you may also mount this config [and try using a different card by default] (/etc/asound.conf)

Comment: Worked for me! However, any luck with Jack Audio?

Comment: Thx, got it to work as root, but I can't make it work with a normal user. Any ideas ? mplayer is giving me `do_connect: could not connect to socket` and `connect: No such file or directory`, as well as a series of `Audio device got stuck...` and no sound.

Comment: @bob this sounds like a permission or missing mount issue. figure out which file socket it tries to open with e.g. strace. make sure its there and you have permission. most of such files are in /tmp or somewhere in /var some may be in home.

Comment: For me everything actually worked with just the ` --privileged` flag (webcam, audio)

Comment: As the other answer shows, for pulseaudio you only need the socket (and the cookie if running as different UID inside) and NOTHING else. -1, absurdly overcomplicated.

Answer (score 9):

Nowdays we have a Pipewire and if you want an application inside of the docker container to play / record sounds using your Pipewire server running on a host, here's what you can do:

1. First of all, we obviously need to have a Pipewire server running on our host. On modern distros the Pipewire is started when systemd reaches `graphical.target` and login manager (gdm, sddm, whatever) is executed. And then, later on, when the user logs in, the Pipewire is restarted to be owned by that user.

In order for the application inside of docker container to use Pipewire, we're going to pass the **socket file descriptor** to that container. For that we need to know who is running the Pipewire server on your host machine. You can check that by looking under whom the pipewire processes is running and then find out what will be the proper socket file:

```
testuser@asrock-ubuntu:~$ ps -fp $(pgrep -d, -x pipewire)

UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
testuser     4250    4206  1 13:32 ?        00:00:27 /usr/bin/pipewire

testuser@asrock-ubuntu:~$ id testuser

uid=1000(testuser) gid=1000(testuser) groups=1000(testuser),4(adm),6(disk),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),105(input),107(kvm),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),140(libvirt),64055(libvirt-qemu),997(docker)
```

So in this our case, I expect there should be a socket file `/run/user/1000/pipewire-0`. Go check that on your system.

2. Now we are going to create a lightweight Alpine docker container, while passing that Pipewire socket file to it and setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable, which is needed for Pipewire client inside of container.

```
docker run -it -v /run/user/1000/pipewire-0:/tmp/pipewire-0 -e XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp --rm alpine /bin/ash
```

3. Inside of the container we install some packages into it, to make the whole thing work:

- alsa-utils - provide a set of ALSA utilities we're going to use as our example software, which needs ALSA
- pipewire - Pipewire server (and client) binaries. But we're not going to run full-fledged server in a container, not at all, we just need its client part to be there
- pipewire-alsa - introduces a virtual ALSA device "pipewire" we're going to use in our software, which requires ALSA. Simply speaking that's the bridge between ALSA and our Pipewire client

```
apk add pipewire-alsa pipewire alsa-utils
```

4. Now let's test if everything works. Make sure you see "pipewire" device when you run `aplay -L` and then run our simple test to play some noise through that device:

```
speaker-test -Dpipewire -c2
```

At this point you should hear a sound coming. If it does not, check your default Pipewire sink device **on your host**. If you're running Gnome, open Gnome Settings -> Sound -> Output

Inside the container, we can now record a wave file with arecord and play it back with using pure ALSA tools:

```
arecord --duration=5 --device=pipewire test.wav
aplay --device=pipewire test.wav
```

5. One last thing, before we go - let's also check that native pipewire clients can be executed inside of that container. For that we install `pipewire-tools`. The example wav file I'm going to play, came with `alsa-utils` pacakge we installed earlier:

```
apk add pipewire-tools
pw-play /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Center.wav
```

In a nutshell, the overall setup is something like this:

[image: resulted setup]

Comment: I really wanted to up-vote this, but I seem to be unable to mount any socket to my container at all except the xorg-server. They just shows up as a dummy files with `ls -l` like so:

`---------- 1 root root 0 date socket-filename`

While expecting this:

`Srw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nobody 0 date socket-filename`

In this particular case the socket-filename happens to be pipewire-0, but it seems like this issue is happening with all mounted sockets, except X0 even though I use the same syntax for mounting. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @JoelSahlin is PipeWire running under the same user you use to spin up docker container? Might be privileges issue

Comment: Everything runs under the same user. I managed to mount my sockets using a different syntax for mounting in the config file, which is weird since the first syntax I used is still working for the x-server. I don't understand why it wouldn't work for other sockets as well.

Comment: @JoelSahlin If the "config file" you're referring to is the docker compose file, then it's likely YAML being weird about particular numbers. Best to specify them as strings (surrounded with quotation marks "like this") instead of raw numbers whenever YAML is involved.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by the links you've posted, I was able to create the following solution. It is as lightweight as I could get it. However, I'm not sure if it is (1) secure, and (2) entirely fits your use-case (as it still uses the network).

1. Install `paprefs`on your host system, e.g. using `sudo apt-get install paprefs` on an Ubuntu machine.
2. Launch PulseAudio Preferences, go to the "Network Server" tab, and check the "Enable network access to local sound devices" checkbox [1]
3. Restart your computer. (Only restarting Pulseaudio didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.10)
4. Install Pulseaudio in your container, e.g. `sudo apt-get install -y pulseaudio`
5. In your container, run `export "PULSE_SERVER=tcp:<host IP address>:<host Pulseaudio port>"`. For example, `export "PULSE_SERVER=tcp:172.16.86.13:4713"` [2]. You can find out your IP address using `ifconfig` and the Pulseaudio port using `pax11publish` [1].
6. That's it. Step 5 should probably be automated if the IP address and Pulseaudio port are subject to change. Additionally, I'm not sure if Docker permanently stores environment variables like `PULSE_SERVER`: If it doesn't then you have to initialize it after each container start.

Suggestions to make my approach even better would be greatly appreciated, since I'm currently working on a similar problem as the OP.

References:
[1] https://github.com/jlund/docker-chrome-pulseaudio
[2] https://github.com/jlund/docker-chrome-pulseaudio/blob/master/Dockerfile

UPDATE (and probably the better solution):
This also works using a Unix socket instead of a TCP socket:

1. Start the container with `-v /run/user/$UID/pulse/native:/path/to/pulseaudio/socket`
2. In the container, run `export "PULSE_SERVER=unix:/path/to/pulseaudio/socket"`

The `/path/to/pulseaudio/socket` can be anything, for testing purposes I used `/home/user/pulse`.
Maybe it will even work with the same path as on the host (taking care of the $UID part) as the default socket, this way the ultimate solution would be `-v /run/user/$UID/pulse/native:/run/user/<UID in container>/pulse`; I haven't tested this however.

Comment: the idea was to get it working without changing the locale PulseAudio preferences (and without using the network connection). but thanks for the information

Comment: You also need to set up the pulse cookie so that you are authorized with the host pulseaudio.  Basically, -v $HOME/.config/pulse/cookie:/run/pulse/cookie:ro or something.  However, changing $PULSE_COOKIE to point to /run/pulse/cookie didn't work for me because the binding is read-only and pulse then falls back to ~/.config/pulse/cookie.  So I did ln -fs /run/pulse/cookie ~/.config/pulse/cookie and that's it.

Comment: Mapping the pulse cookie wasn't required for me.  Perhaps because I was already running the container with the host uid:gid?

Answer (score 5):

After trying most of the solutions described here I found only [PulseAudio over network](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network) to be really working. However you can make it safe by keeping the authentication.

1. Install **paprefs** (on host machine):

   ```
   $ apt-get install paprefs
   ```
2. Launch `paprefs` (PulseAudio Preferences) > Network Server > [X] Enable network access to local sound devices.
3. Restart PulseAudio:

   ```
   $ service pulseaudio restart
   ```
4. Check it worked or restart machine:

   ```
   $ (pax11publish || xprop -root PULSE_SERVER) | grep -Eo 'tcp:[^ ]*'
   tcp:myhostname:4713
   ```

Now use that socket:

```
$ docker run \
    -e PULSE_SERVER=tcp:$(hostname -i):4713 \
    -e PULSE_COOKIE=/run/pulse/cookie \
    -v ~/.config/pulse/cookie:/run/pulse/cookie \
    ...
```

Check that the user running inside the container has access to the cookie file `~/.config/pulse/cookie`.

To test it works:

```
$ apt-get install mplayer
$ mplayer /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

For more info may check [Docker Mopidy](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wernight/mopidy/) project.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming pulseaudio is installed on host and in image, one can provide pulseaudio sound over tcp with only a few steps. pulseaudio does not need to be restarted, and no configuration has to be done on host or in image either. This way it is included in [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker), without the need of VNC or SSH:

First, [find a free tcp port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-an-unused-local-port):

```
read LOWERPORT UPPERPORT < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
while : ; do
  PULSE_PORT="`shuf -i $LOWERPORT-$UPPERPORT -n 1`"
  ss -lpn | grep -q ":$PULSE_PORT " || break
done
```

Get ip adress of docker daemon. I always find it being 172.17.42.1/16

```
ip -4 -o a | grep docker0 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Load pulseaudio tcp module, authenticate connection to docker ip:

```
PULSE_MODULE_ID=$(pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp port=$PULSE_PORT auth-ip-acl=172.17.42.1/16)
```

On docker run, create environment variable PULSE_SERVER

```
docker run -e PULSE_SERVER=tcp:172.17.42.1:$PULSE_PORT yourimage
```

Afterwards, unload tcp module. (Note: for unknown reasons, unloading this module can stop pulseaudio daemon on host):

```
pactl unload-module $PULSE_MODULE_ID
```

---

Edit: [How-To for ALSA and Pulseaudio in container](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Container-sound:-ALSA-or-Pulseaudio)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dockerize a Java game in the following ways, effectively passing through the game's sound.

This approach requires building an image, making sure the app has all the dependencies it'll need, in this case, pulseaudio and x11. If you're sure your images has everything it needs, you may procees as stated in the previous answers.

Here, we need to build the image, then we can actually launch it.

```bash
docker build -t my-unciv-image . # Run from directory where Dockerfile is
docker run --name unciv # image name\ 
  --device /dev/dri \
  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
  -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \
  --privileged \
  -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -v /path/to/Unciv:/App \
  -v /run/user/$(id -u)/pulse:/run/user/(id -u)/pulse \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  -w /App \
  my-unciv-image \
  java -jar /App/Unciv.jar
```

In the second command the following is specified:

- `--name`: a name is given to the container
- `--device`: video device*
- `-e`: required environment vars

  - `DISPLAY`: the display number
  - `PULSE_SERVER`: PulseAudio audio server socket
- `--privileged`: run ip privileged*, so it can access all devices
- `-v`: Mounted volumes:

  - Path to the game mounted into /App in the container**
  - Audio server socke
  - Display server socket
- `-w`: Working directory

Here is a `docker-compose.yml` version of it:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  unciv:
    build: .
    container_name: unciv
    devices:
      - /dev/dri:/dev/dri # * Either this
    entrypoint: java -jar /App/Unciv.jar
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
      - PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native
    privileged: true # * or this
    user: 1000:1000
    volumes:
      - /path/to/game/:/App
      - /run/user/1000/pulse:/run/user/1000/pulse
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    working_dir: /App
```

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openjdk-11-jre -y
RUN apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-video-all
RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
RUN apt-get install -y pulseaudio

USER unciv
```

Notes:

- *Only required for a game or anything that uses openGL. Either passing the devices explicitly or running it as privileged, but I think it's enough to pass the device, making it privileged may be overkill.
- **This math may be bundled with the docker image, but for a demo.
- For the audio, it's required to pass env variable `PULSE_SERVER` and mounting the pulseaudio socket