# Making use of docker for development: a use case

Tags: docker, lxc-docker

my question is little vague but I tried looking for the answer here and there but could not understand if I can leverage docker for my work. My requirements 
I usually try different versions of java, python and other software like different versions of eclipse, Linux package and other tools. This at the end make my Ubuntu installation a complete mess and some time completely broken.  Then I started using Vm it solve most of the problem but make my pc very slow for frequent switching.

So my question can I achieve my work using docker without affecting my os? Can I run gui application,  install different package without affecting underlying OS. 
Switch actively between different docker container and underlying os.
Clean/remove  unused/broken install of docker instance (containers?) etc. Any pointer to similar use case or how to would be helpful.
Thanks.

Ps- if it doesn't fit for SO then please move it to where it is best fitted.  Sorry for non programming question.

Comment: I wrote http://dockershell.io/ for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Can it be done?

yes, there are examples of docker images that run graphical application, but running those containers might be a bit tricky. See for instance [Can you run GUI apps in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container)

#### Is Docker the right tool for your problem ?

Maybe a package manager such as [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) would be better suited, as graphical software installed with it won't have any issue. With Nix you can install side-by-side many versions of a single software without interference.

Comment: If you want to use several versions of Python, you should use virtualenv http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: That is also true but only applies to python. Nix allows the same whatever the software

Comment: Its not just python.Its the whole lot of dependency problem when you install one version of package which makes other broke. constantly changing ends in unmanageable system. what I'm looking is for a use and throw/plug and play approach, where I just keep what I need install it after use scrap it without disturbing other or underlying OS.