# How to run headless testing in Robot Framework

Tags: firefox, robotframework, headless

I want to run my Testcases in a headless environment using `xvfb` through Jenkins.

Can any one help me with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker with GUI application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444835/docker-with-gui-application)

Comment: @Goralight thanks for reply  that is only for Docker and i am facing issue on jenkins and linux server.

Comment: ? I didnt say anything? I presume you meant Evedel.

Comment: Sorry @Goralight yes it is for evedel

Answer (score -1):

Try using phantomJS, docker image link https://hub.docker.com/r/cmfatih/phantomjs/