# Docker run desktop environment

Tags: docker, vnc, xvfb

The question is most clear,
How to start complete desktop environment (KDE, XFCE, Gnome doesn't matter) in the Docker **remote** container.

I were digging over the internet and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers/25334301#25334301) [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444835/docker-with-gui-application) of questions about the related topic, but not the same, they all about how to run GUI **application** not the full desktop.

What I found out:

- Necessary run Xvfb
- Somehow run e.g. Xfce in that FrameBuffer
- Allow x11vnc to share that running X environment

But I'm stuck here actually, always getting whatever errors:

```
... (EE) Invalid screen configuration 1024x768 for -screen 0
... Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
```

Could you give some Dockerfile lines in order reach the goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is I was looking for, the simplest form of the **desktop** in Docker:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install xfce4 -y
RUN apt-get install xfce4-goodies -y
RUN apt-get purge -y pm-utils xscreensaver*
RUN apt-get install wget -y

EXPOSE 5901

RUN wget -qO- https://dl.bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/tigervnc-1.8.0.x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C /
RUN mkdir ~/.vnc
RUN echo "123456" | vncpasswd -f >> ~/.vnc/passwd
RUN chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd


CMD ["/usr/bin/vncserver", "-fg"]
```

Unfortunately I could not sort out with **x11vnc** and **xvfb**. But [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/) turned out much better.

This sample generate container with xfce gui and run **vncserver** with 123456 password. There is **no need** to overwrite *~/.vnc/xstartup* manually because TigerVNC starts up X server by default!

To run the server:

```
sudo docker run --rm -dti -p 5901:5901 3ab3e0e7cb
```

To connect there with [vncviewer](http://tigervnc.org/doc/vncviewer.html):

```
vncviewer -AutoSelect 0 -QualityLevel 9 -CompressLevel 0 192.168.1.100:5901
```

Also you could not care about screen resolution because by default it will  resize to fit your screen:
[image: F8 vncviewer menu]

You may also encounter the [issue with ipc_channel_posix](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/388) (chrome and other browsers will not work properly) to eliminate this run container with [memory sharing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images):

```
docker run -d --shm-size=2g --privileged -p 5901:5901 image-name
```

Comment: Can we have a solution for an EC2 instance too?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I think it doesn't matter where the container will be deployed. You only should be careful about port forwarding

Answer (score 3):

[x11docker allows to run desktop environments as well as single GUI applications in docker.](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)

> Could you give some Dockerfile lines in order reach the goal?

[Example desktop images on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/x11docker/).

x11docker does a lot of setup to keep container isolation and provides some additional options like hardware acceleration or pulseaudio sound. Example:

```
x11docker --desktop x11docker/lxde
```

---

x11docker also supports [network setups with SSH, VNC and HTML5](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker#network-setup)

Example for SSH setup with xpra:

```
read Xenv < <(x11docker --xdummy --display=30 x11docker/lxde pcmanfm)
echo $Xenv && export $Xenv
# replace "start" with "start-desktop" to forward a desktop environment
xpra start :30 --use-display --start-via-proxy=no
```

From client system, connect with

```
xpra attach ssh:HOSTNAME:30  # replace HOSTNAME with IP or host name of ssh server
```

---

Without x11docker:

A quite short setup using Xephyr as nested X server on host is:

```
Xephyr :1
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X1:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1:rw \
           -e DISPLAY=:1 \
           x11docker/xfce
```

A short Dockerfile with Xfce desktop:

```
FROM debian:stretch
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends xfce4 dbus-x11
CMD startxfce4
```

Comment: Great `x11docker` project! and many thanks for answer, but unfortunately I need **remote** vnc connection.

Comment: It is possible to set up a VNC connection with x11docker, I have edited the answer. Though, I am not experienced with VNC. Compare this diskussion: https://github.com/mviereck/dockerfile-x11docker-xfce-wine-playonlinux/issues/1 . An SSH setup with xpra works quite well and is more tested.