# Custom Windows Docker Container Base Image

Tags: docker, docker-container, windows-container

I have a service that uses an API for a desktop software. I currently have this deployed by VM's. On the VM I have the required desktop software and my service. This works great. I am wondering is it possible to install the required desktop software into a Windows Docker Image? I have tried before, but I run into the problem of no GUI in the Docker Container. The Desktop software can only be installed via a GUI installer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker run desktop environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955823/docker-run-desktop-environment)

Comment: @PeterBadida That seems to be a Linux approach, I forgot to mention I am running in a Windows environment

Comment: In that case the duplicate is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67735018/5994041). You basically need to start an RDP server (or possibly a VNC server via cygwin or alternatives) while having a graphical session enabled and working (up to your image, drivers, etc). Afterwards you can connect via RDP or VNC and mount the folders, then do your installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Windows containers don't provide a GUI/desktop, so any app that is dependent on that won't work on Windows containers.

I blogged about this here: https://cda.ms/4hB and explained that Windows containers have the underlying GUI APIs available so if your application relies on those APIs, it would still work, but is the dependency extends to the desktop itself, then it won't work.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I just added more details to the answer.