# How to open Ubuntu GUI inside a Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-image

I have downloaded the Ubuntu image inside Docker on Windows.

I can run Ubuntu by:

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

I only see `root`, but I don't see the Ubuntu GUI. How do I install or configure the GUI for that image and run applications on that GUI like we run in a VM?

Comment: What's the use-case for needing the Ubuntu GUI from a docker container? Docker generally runs headless, so you could install X and run a VNC server or something I guess... but seems odd.

Comment: Docker images are supposed to run one app most typically a server or a compute app. Sometimes it gets to more that one app but usually not to serve the UI. UI needs lot more for which docker is not a good use case.

Comment: i actually want to code python and debug all the things in the image, what would be the way to do so inside ubuntu image ?

Comment: `all the things`. Please be more specific. You want to debug your python code, or more?

Comment: i want to setup complete tools to develop in python, visual studio code editor, firefox, dropbox to manage that code and same basic apps

Comment: Use a VM then. This doesn't sound like an appropriate use of docker _at all_.

Comment: Probably [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container).

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766270/download-and-run-ubuntu-desktop-with-gnome-support-via-docker/59287775#59287775

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the approach for developing with Docker is to keep the IDE on the workstation, and build images with the binary produced from the sources.

You can find many example of such a workflow (local compilation, deployment in Docker containers) in [domeide.github.io/ (Docker meets the IDE!)](http://domeide.github.io/)
For example: [Docker Tools for VisualStudio](https://aka.ms/dockertoolsforvs) allows for a tight integration between your editor and Docker processes.

[image: https://microsoftcloudexplorer.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/microsoftcloudexplorer/visualstudiotoolsfordocker-preview/0.41.0/1478598789732/205468/1/add-docker-support.png]

(But this is for Visual Studio 2015, not Visual Studio Code.)

Comment: thanks for clearing me , i guess i have to code python in visual studio code in my VS Code in host workstation and use the images of ubuntu python libraries docker images , right ? and build using that

Comment: @ShanKhan That is the idea, yes. You can mount local folders into containers with docker run -v with data volumes (https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

Comment: The last link is broken (404).

Answer (score 84):

**`fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop`**

https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop provides a convenient setup:

```
sudo docker run --name ubvnc -p 6080:80 -p 5900:5900 dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc:bionic
```

Then on host either:

- visit: http://127.0.0.1:6080/#/ which runs a [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) more limited JavaScript VNC client
- run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install tigervnc-viewer
  xtigervncviewer :5900
  ```

  To go into fullscreen mode, hit F8 and click on menu entry, or just F8 followed by T: https://superuser.com/questions/285843/how-do-i-switch-in-out-of-fullscreen-mode-from-the-command-line-in-realvnc You might need to close and reopen the screen after that for the image to get larger.

  I also tried `vinagre`, but it was much laggier when scrolling Firefox on YouTube.

  Inside `vinagre`, you might want to [go into full screen mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387045/how-to-exit-fullscreen-mode-in-vinagre/435274#435274) to be able to see the full desktop

[image]

To quit just kill `docker` on the terminal. And to restart the machine:

```
sudo docker start ubvnc
```

and then reconnect with VNC. Then to quit the machine:

```
sudo docker stop ubvnc
```

You have to wait a few seconds for the VNC server on the guest to start before you can connect.

Chromium inside the guest won't start from the menu. If you try to launch it from the command line it explains why:

```
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

so just run it from the CLI with:

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox
```

Firefox does not care however.

TODO: no audio. `--device /dev/snd` did not help:

- [How to play sound in a Docker container on Mac OS Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083436/how-to-play-sound-in-a-docker-container)
- https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-get-sound/36527
- https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop/issues/49

EDIT: they added a section for it: https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop/tree/e4922ce92f945fc482994b7a0fd95ca5de7295b3#sound-preview-version-and-linux-only

See also:

- [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container)

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 19.04 host, `fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop`, `dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc` image id: 70516b87e92d.
- Ubuntu 21.10 host, `dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc:focal` (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: On windows machines we can install a vncviewer like realvnc and connect to 127.0.0.1:5900.

Comment: this is one of the best working "x in vnc" solutions out there. I just wish it was gnome :/

Comment: How can i share clipboard with host (copy on host->paste on client)?

Comment: @Kopernik I don't know, see also https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop/issues/272

Answer (score 6):

You can directly connect a Docker container to your [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server.

See Stack Overflow question *[Can you run GUI applications in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/25280523#25280523)*.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple way to solve this.

A common problem is that the docker doesn't have permission to access the display, so run the command below on your computer.

```
$ xhost +
```

After that, you need to know the param of your display.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
```

Now, open your docker as root.

```
$ docker container run --rm --net host -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -it image_name:tag
```

Give the param of your display to the container.

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
```

Now you can run your GUI application.

Comment: This is a good method to start with, but it's very insecure, because the container could eventually gain control over the host system via X11.

Comment: Good information, thanks!