# How can I create rails projects with docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

### What I want

I want to create Rails projects with docker

### Problem

When I command this, The error is happend

```
 sudo docker-compose run api rails new . --force --no-deps --database=po stgresql
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

### refer to URL

[standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" - Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory)

### code

docker-compose

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /api
WORKDIR /api
COPY ./api/Gemfile /api/Gemfile
COPY ./api/Gemfile.lock /api/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY ./api/ /api

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

### version

docker-compose v3
rails v6

How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this?  Does your Rails application work without Docker involved at all?

Comment: The building is success but it will exit soon. when I log, "api_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" showed

Comment: Can I ask why you’re trying to create a new rails project directly in docker? It’s far simpler to create the project in rails normally then run with `rails s`

Comment: https://github.com/ledermann/docker-rails start from here