# Docker: how to map host directory?

Tags: docker

I am trying to reproduce steps to create an Ubuntu based image + nginx, described there:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/

My host machine is Windows.
The image is built, then I have created d:\webroot folder on host, index.html file inside and try to run

```
docker run  -v /d/webroot:/var/www/html -p 80:80 --name doom nginx_image

standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

What may be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running this on windows machine?

Comment: Yes, my host is Windows

Comment: Can you try using `d:/webroot:/var/www/html` in your docker command above? And see if that works.

Comment: # docker run  -v d:/webroot:/var/www/html -p 80:80 --name doom nginx_image
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/www/html.

Comment: The drive mount doesn't look like the issue. Your original format seems fine (`/d/webroot:/var/www/html`). Can you check this for your `start.sh` script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thnx. Add your comment as an answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the [`start.sh`](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/) script which is loaded from Windows. Excerpt below:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

You need to change the change line ending from `CRLF` to `LF` for the `start.sh`.

And then run: `docker run  -v /d/webroot:/var/www/html -p 80:80 --name doom nginx_image`