# How to install nc in mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am getting this message
`nc command is missing` and by doing some R&D, I got to know that in order to resolve this, (I think) I need to run below command in MySQL container in docker-compose

```
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
```

But the issue is I don't have it's docker file else I could have written this command in docker file and might have called docker file from docker-compose

Does anyone have any idea how can I run this command from docker-compose?

**Edit 1:**
I have made separate the DockerFile for mysql which consists of

```
FROM mysql:8
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
COPY wait-for.sh .
```

and then called this docker file from docker-compose which goes like this...

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql-standalone:
        image: mysql:8.0.25
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=********
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=usermanagementappdp
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        depends_on: ['eureka-server']
        build:
            context: "./mysqlDockerFile2"
            dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
        volumes:
            - ./wait-for:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        entrypoint: ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/wait-for.sh", "eureka-server:8761", "--", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql-standalone
            PMA_USER: root
            PMA_PASSWORD: root123M.
        ports:
            - 8085:80

    eureka-server:
        image: eureka-server
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
        build:
            context: "../Eureka-Server-For-User-Management-App"
            dockerfile: "Dockerfile"


    usermanagementapp-docker:
        image: usermanagementapp-docker:latest
        ports:
            - 8089:8089
        links:
            - eureka-server
        environment:
            EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/usermanagementappdp?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
        build:
            context: "./"
            dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
        restart: on-failure
        entrypoint: ["/wait-for.sh", "mysql-standalone:3306", "--", "['java','-jar','/app.jar']"]
        depends_on: ['mysql-standalone','eureka-server']
```

Docker file for User management app is:

```
FROM openjdk:8
Add target/User-Management-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8089
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
COPY wait-for.sh .
COPY target/User-Management-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Docker file for Eureka- server

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8761
ADD /target/Eureka-Server-For-User-Management-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar netflix-eureka-server-1.0.jar
COPY wait-for.sh .
netflix-eureka-server-1.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","netflix-eureka-server-1.0.jar"]
```

**Edit 2**
I just edited mysql docker file to check if it is even getting executed or not

```
RUN echo "'Entered in docker file of mysql'"
FROM mysql:8
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
COPY wait-for.sh .

RUN echo "'Exiting docker file of mysql'"
```

and found that on doing `docker-compose up` it is not echoing the text

Comment: Why do you need `nc` in a MySQL server container?  Do you maybe need this in your application container instead, to support something like the `wait-for-it` script?  (And that you should have the Dockerfile for.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes. I am using wait-for.sh script. I have updated the question. Please recheck the "Edit 1 " section. When I am using wait-for.sh script. It is giving me "nc is missing error". I am suffering from this error since 5 days and haven't found solution. Please help if you have knowledge about it.

Comment: You are using both `image` and `build` in a single service definition. I think `docker-compose` skip `build` section because requested `image` are presented locally. Try to remove `image: ...`.

Comment: @Anton if I would remove "image" then it wont pull the image file from docker hub I think. Build I am using to run Docker file. Let me know if I am wrong?

Comment: @user123 `docker` will pull it while building your custom image from your `Dockerfile`  (because you set `mysql:8` as base image in `FROM mysql:8` line)

Comment: @Anton I tried what you said.. On doing so it has stopped giving 'nc command is missing ' error. But it is now exiting like "user-management-app_mysql-standalone_1 exited with code 0" without showing any reason. Earlier I knew it was happening due to 'nc command is missing'. But this time there is no reason in the logs. Any Pointers?

Comment: @user123 Use `docker-compose logs` to see what happens

Comment: @Anton No logs are printed there for MySQL. The logs printed there are only for Eureka-server, phpMyAdmin and myApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install `netcat` in the database server container.  There are a couple of other things you can clean up to simplify this setup.

Let's start by thinking through what needs to happen when you run `docker-compose up`.  The application container can't function until the database is up and running; for that, the application container is using the `wait-for` script, which in turn uses `nc`.  The database itself doesn't need to make any outbound connections, though; it needs to start up and accept *inbound* connections so the rest of the system can proceed.  So you don't need `nc` in the database server container, and you can just use the standard unmodified `mysql` image.

(In your Dockerfile you show the database depending on the Eureka service registry; but the database itself won't do anything to connect to it, and you're using a direct connection to the database from your application.  It doesn't need to be part of this stack.)

Your Compose setup also overrides the image's `entrypoint:`.  This shouldn't usually be necessary.  I'd suggest a pattern where the image's `ENTRYPOINT` is a self-contained script that ends with a shell `exec "$@"` command, which will let it run the `CMD` passed to it as arguments.  So that script could look something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# ./entrypoint.sh

# Set defaults for common environment variables
: ${MYSQL_PORT:=3306}
: ${MYSQL_DATABASE:=usermanagementappdp}

# Wait for the database to be ready
./wait-for.sh "$MYSQL_HOST:$MYSQL_PORT"

# Dynamically set the Spring database URL
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_HOST:$MYSQL_PORT/$MYSQL_DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Then in your *application's* Dockerfile -- again, you don't need to change anything in the database's Dockerfile -- set this script as the `ENTRYPOINT`, and make your `java -jar` command the `CMD`.

```sh
FROM openjdk:8

# Install OS-level dependencies before COPYing anything in
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      netcat

# COPY in the actual application (don't usually ADD things)
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/User-Management-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
COPY wait-for.sh entrypoint.sh .

# Set metadata for how to run the application
EXPOSE 8089
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Now in your `docker-compose.yml` setup you can get rid of most of the overrides.  Run an unmodified `mysql` image and don't override the `command:` or `entrypoint:` of anything.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    mysql-standalone:
        image: mysql:8.0.25
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=********
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=usermanagementappdp
        ports:
            - 3306:3306

    phpmyadmin: { image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin, ... }

    eureka-server:
        build: ../Eureka-Server-For-User-Management-App

    usermanagementapp-docker:
        ports:
            - 8089:8089
        environment:
            EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
            MYSQL_HOST: mysql-standalone
        build: .
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on: [mysql-standalone, eureka-server]
```

The setup you show above will contaminate your local copy of the MySQL image, so before you start, you should clean it up

```sh
docker pull mysql:8.0.25
```

---

If you need to do some sort of registration in the MySQL image at startup time, then you can follow this same basic approach.  It is helpful to look up the [Docker Hub `mysql` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) and from there [its Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/15fe7357b165ee8aaa3ce165386f910a53a75087/8.0/Dockerfile.debian) because you will need to know the original `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

In the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script, at the end, run the original entrypoint:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# my-entrypoint.sh
...
exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$@" # running the original entrypoint
```

In your derived Dockerfile, you'll need to repeat the original `CMD`

```sh
FROM mysql:8.0.27
...
COPY wait-for.sh my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["my-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

In your Compose file, **do not specify both `image: mysql` and a `build:` block**.  This will overwrite your local copy of the Docker Hub image with your custom build.  For most purposes you can only specify `build:` and ignore `image:`.  You do not need to use `volumes:` to inject code, that's contained within the custom Dockerfile.

```yaml
services:
    mysql-standalone:
        build: ./mysql
        # no image:
```

Comment: Thanks for your so deeply explained answer. I found you have written ".... which in turn uses nc. The database itself doesn't need to make any outbound connections, though; it needs to start up and accept inbound connections so the rest of the system can proceed..." I think you didn't get the flow of the app properly. Its right that my app is waiting for MySQL to startup but further MySql IS WAITING for Eureka-server to startup. Means first Eureaka should start completely then MySQl complete and THEN myApp. I think that's why it needs nc command to be there in MySQL container. Isn't it?

Comment: Also @David Maze ,the entrypoint.sh The script code which you provided, in that you have told "# Run the main container command
exec "$@"" . So do I need to put something after $@? Do I need to put container ID of myApp container, MySQL container or Eureka-server container?

Comment: As I implemented your code..  Eureka server and MySQL has started succefully but for myApp It is giving me this error "usermanagementapp-docker_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"". I think I need to add something in last line of entrypoint.sh... after $@... but not sure what is that. Please let me know if there is something else which is causing this error.

Comment: In an entrypoint script, `exec "$@"` will run the image's `CMD` (or an overridden Compose `command:`).  You don't need to put anything after it.

Comment: Okay. But now I am getting "usermanagementapp-docker_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"" as I told in above comment. would be very helpful if you can help with this? Eureka server and MySQL has started successfully, but MySQL is starting before Eureka server. Where as it should have waited for Eureka server to start first completely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory The first answer in this solution solved my  issue of "standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory""

Answer (score 0):

You could build and publish your own container image if you wanted with a dockerfile like this

```
FROM mysql:8
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
```

and build it like `docker build . -t user123/mysql:8`

and push it like `docker push user123/mysql:8`

then switch your docker compose to use your custom container.

if you just need to pop in temporarily to install netcat, you can do that by doing

`docker exec -it --user=root ContainerHashOrName /bin/bash` where `ContainerHashOrName` can be retrieved from `docker ps` then just run your commands like you would on any other distro. Just be aware that you are only making changes to the specific *instance* of a container and that any rescheduling will bring up a different instance of the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Junkiebev. But I am still facing the same issue. mysql-standalone_1          | nc command is missing! I have updated the question in Edit1 section. Please check

Comment: I am building docker file for mysql using this command --- "docker build -f Dockerfile -t  mysql:8.0.25 ." and it says "Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.168kB
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context"

Answer (score 0):

You can use "build" option of compose file, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build and use your own `Dockerfile` starts with `FROM mysql:8` and then install all additional stuff you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Junkiebev. But I am still facing the same issue. mysql-standalone_1          | nc command is missing! I have updated the question in Edit1 section. Please check