# Why my docker Fail "exec /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I'm trying to run container in docker with windows 11. When I'm running docker compose up web server, it shows `exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`, but it does exist in folder, and it also  shows in web container files.

And the db container is running and worked.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 5442:5432
  web:
    environment:
      - GMAIL_USER=gmailuser@gmail.com
      - GMAIL_PASSWORD=gmailpassword
    build: ./
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev make
# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# run entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
# python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
if [ $ENV = "prod" ]; then python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; fi
python manage.py loaddata */fixtures/*.json
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.filter(email='admin@domain').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('admin@domain', 'password')" | python manage.py shell
exec "$@"
```

Thank you for your help!

I tried to:

1. `docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> sh`, but can't be entry because container not running.
2. `docker run -v /local/path/to/entrypoint.sh:/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh my_image`, but I still get `exec /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`

Comment: What is the content of entrypoint.sh?

Comment: The `docker run -v` option and Compose `volumes:` overwrite everything in the image, including the entrypoint script, so this is hard to make reproducible.  Does [standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" - Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory) help you?  You say you're on a Windows host; more specifically, can you double-check that your entrypoint script (on the host, with those volume mounts) has Unix and not DOS line endings?

Comment: love u guys, it CLRF question! I change to LF, and it'll work.