# Python Tkinter in Docker .TclError: couldn't connect to display

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, tkinter, xfce

I am new to python and am trying to build a small app. It needs to be a GUI app and I was wanting to containerise it with docker. I am getting the following error and can not find a solution

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinker.py", line 7, in <module>
    tinker = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

It starts locally but wont start in docker. My OS is Xubuntu.

I have created a sample app (below), see run-test.sh https://github.com/jeremysells/test/tree/master/docker-tkinter

Comment: Again, adding `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` is not enough.

Comment: It might be OS specific but I would not think so. Does anyone know if I have to configure anything locally to get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were on Mac

Answer (score 4):

As [described here](https://hub.docker.com/r/dorakorpar/nsgui/), you would need an X11 graphic layer.
But since you are already on an '(X)Ubuntu, setting the DISPLAY should be enough:

```
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0

docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix yourImage
```

Check also [XAuthority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280523/6309).

Comment: See also https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8710#issuecomment-71113263 to expose local xquartz socket on a TCP port.

Answer (score 3):

Type `xhost +` in your terminal. Then

```
docker run --rm \
    --network=host --privileged \
    -v /dev:/dev \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority \
    -it yourimage
```

worked for me. `xhost +` disables access control. After which a client can connect from any host.

Comment: "Connect" here implies being able to run things like screen captures and keystroke loggers: you really don't want to allow this ability "from any host".

Comment: So, what is the better alternative, @DavidMaze ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set DISPLAY in the container. You can add it as an argument to the docker run command like this:

```
docker run -ti -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY blah-image blah-command
```

DISPLAY should be set in the Xubuntu shell you are running the command from.

Comment: Saidly same issue
# docker run -ti -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY tkinter-test:latest
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "tkinker.py", line 7, in <module>
        tinker = Tk()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
        self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"

Comment: Is display set in the shell where you start the command? Are you able to run GUIs from outside of docker?

Comment: Yes the display is enabled. When I run `#echo $DISPLAY` it returns ":0.0". I wonder if it has something to do with xauth (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container and http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI). I don't have any free time at the moment, so will have to get back to testing this when I do

Comment: Use the IP address of your Linux/UNIX system (not the Docker container).  For example, `-e DISPLAY=10.0.0.1:0.0` (replace `10.0.0.1` with the IP address of your Linux/UNIX system).

Answer (score 0):

Derived from [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040181/728675) and inspired by [its such comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445047/python-tkinter-in-docker-tclerror-couldnt-connect-to-display#comment105321046_57040181), my quest ends up with 2 workable solutions. Pick either one you prefer.

- `xhost local:root && docker -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix your_image`
- `xhost local:root && docker -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --net=host your_image`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to run on you current screen, it looks like docker has some nice DNS stuff built in for that:

```
docker run -ti -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 appname
```

and for vscode in `launch.json` add this to the end of your configuration.

```
"env": {
    "DISPLAY": "host.docker.internal:0"
}
```

Then, of course, if you are running windows, you need something like xming to receive the X11 packets.