# How to install python-tk in my docker image

Tags: python, docker, python-2.x

I get this error when I run my python script in my docker image

```
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

So I tried 'pip install python-tk'

```
root@43d2222b15c8:/tf_files# pip install python-tk
Collecting python-tk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-tk
```

But that does not fix my issue.

Can you please tell me how can I fix my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: This topic is similar to your problem. Check pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python

Comment: i tried both  apt-get install python3-tk and  apt-get install python-tk. Both said no installation candidate.  And I am doing that in a docker image. Will that make a difference?

Comment: what's base image did you use ? Try ubuntu please. and use ap-get install python-tk.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613117/why-does-conda-install-tk-not-work-in-my-docker-container-even-though-it-says-it

Comment: `python-tk` is a system package, not a Python package. It cannot be installed using `pip`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `import Tkinter`. It should not be required via pip. It's built into python2.7 (Assuming you are using python2.7 since this post is tagged with it. If you are using 3 then it's a different solution and what the people in comments are referencing.)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#module-Tkinter

Answer (score -1):

It is probably not a problem with the package not being installed but rather not running because of lack of display.

For convenience I'm pasting the code how to do that:

docker run -ti -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY blah-image blah-command

Extracted from here:
[Python Tkinter in Docker .TclError: couldn't connect to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445047/python-tkinter-in-docker-tclerror-couldnt-connect-to-display)