# Why does conda install tk not work in my docker container even though it says its installed?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I was having issues with `tk` in my python 3 docker container.

I tried:

```
conda install tk
```

but it says it did install it

```
root@36602e2cd649:/home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/pytorch_experiments# conda install tk
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /opt/conda:
#
tk                        8.6.7                h5979e9b_1
```

but when I go to python and try to import it it does not work:

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

and other errors:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I run a script that needs it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bulk_experiment_dispatcher.py", line 18, in <module>
    from data_file import *
  File "/home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/pytorch_experiments/data_file.py", line 16, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried `apt-get install python-tk` (from [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)) but it did not work:

```
root@36602e2cd649:/home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/pytorch_experiments# apt-get install python-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-tk
```

---

I tried running `ENTERYPOINT` as one of the answers suggested but it threw me some more errors:

```
/path/fake_gui.sh: 8: /home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/docker_files/runtime/fake_gui.sh: source: not found
/path/fake_gui.sh: 12: /home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/docker_files/runtime/fake_gui.sh: function: not found
/path/fake_gui.sh: 13: kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGTERM
/path/fake_gui.sh: 15: /home_simulation_research/overparametrized_experiments/docker_files/runtime/fake_gui.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

but not sure what to do...

---

Helpful questions:

[How to install python-tk in my docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289891/how-to-install-python-tk-in-my-docker-image)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Docker container that has a [virtual framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) installed and running.

This [blog post](https://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/running-a-gui-application-in-a-docker-container/) explains the "Why and How" of putting X11 into a docker container.

You can see how they're doing it in the Selenium Docker container via their `entry_point.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# IMPORTANT: Change this file only in directory Standalone!

source /opt/bin/functions.sh

export GEOMETRY="$SCREEN_WIDTH""x""$SCREEN_HEIGHT""x""$SCREEN_DEPTH"

function shutdown {
  kill -s SIGTERM $NODE_PID
  wait $NODE_PID
}

if [ ! -z "$SE_OPTS" ]; then
  echo "appending selenium options: ${SE_OPTS}"
fi

SERVERNUM=$(get_server_num)

rm -f /tmp/.X*lock

xvfb-run -n $SERVERNUM --server-args="-screen 0 $GEOMETRY -ac +extension RANDR" \
  java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar \
  ${SE_OPTS} &
NODE_PID=$!

trap shutdown SIGTERM SIGINT
wait $NODE_PID
```

*Source for the above code is from this repository on GitHub, [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneChrome).*

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused, how does this install `tkinter` in python?

Comment: tkinter is generally installed by default, however just because it's installed doesn't mean you can use it. The error you're getting is because there's no GUI inside your docker container.

Comment: not sure whats wrong but it threw me a couple of weird errors...that I thought would be already included: `source: not found`, `function: not found`, `kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGTERM` and `Syntax error: "}" unexpected`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: this is really weird, I can't install `xvfb`...I ran `RUN apt-get install -y xvfb` but it can't find it: 'E: Unable to locate package xvfb'...

Comment: @CharlieParker why are you trying to create windows in a docker container?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so once I put a dummy screen in the image it stopped crashing:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
#RUN Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &> xvfb.log  &
```

when I ran my docker image.

Comment: Interestingly, based on the command `apt` you used, @CharlieParker you probably used this `xvfb` thing in a Debian-based image, such as `python:3-slim`. But in my recent journey, `xvfb` was NOT necessary in `python:3-slim` based image in the first place. However, your hint actually helped me to do `apk add xvfb` in an Alpine-based image such as `python:3-alpine`, and that got the tkinter working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With python 3, you must import as follows:

```
import tkinter   # with a small caps 't'
```

Comment: that still raises an error, but thanks that of course matters: `import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`...put the whole error in original question.