# Accessing Docker container other than ssh

Tags: android, docker

Have downloaded Android docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/yongjhih/android-studio/

Usage is defined as :

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/yongjhih/docker-android-studio/raw/master/docker-android-studio > ~/bin/android-studio
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/android-studio

$ android-studio
```

I've pulled the repo via `docker pull yongjhih/android-studio` but now I'm unsure how to use it. To date I've just access docker containers via ssh.

In order to use the IDE I'll need to get 'window' access to the environment running the IDE ?

Looking at the dockerFIle (https://hub.docker.com/r/yongjhih/android-studio/~/dockerfile/) this environment appears to be Ubuntu : `ENV USER ubuntu`

Is there a Docker recommended method of accessing a container of this type ?

Update :

The docker container has been pulled to Ubuntu 14.04. My understanding is the docker container is running the IDE, how to use the IDE ?

Comment: The instructions in the docker hub page you've linked to refer to a linux/mac setup, is this what you use for running your IDE?

Comment: @YaronIdan I'm running the docker container containing the Android IDE on OS Ubuntu14.04. Please see question update for more detail.

Comment: You need to learn about SSH X Window forwarding

Comment: For example, running Firefox using the same logic as that AS container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971413/2308683