# Add xserver into Docker container (the host is headless)

Tags: docker, containers, headless, xserver

I'm building a Docker container which have maven and some dependencies. Then it execute a script inside the container. It seems, one of that dependencies needs an Xserver to work. Nothing is shown on screen but it seems necessary and can't be avoided.

I got it working putting an `ENV DISPLAY=x.x.x.x:0` on Dockerfile and it connects to the external Xserver and it works. But the point is to make a Docker self-sufficient container.

So I need to add a Xserver to my container adding in Dockerfile the necessary. And I want that Xserver only accessible by the Docker container itself and not externally.

The `FROM` of my Dockerfile is `FROM ubuntu:15.04` and that is unchangeable because my Dockerfile have a lot of things depending of that specific version.

I've read some post about how to connect from docker container to Xserver of the Docker host machine, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container/25168483#25168483). But as I put in question's title, the Docker host is headless and doesn't have Xserver.

- Which would be the minimum `apt-get` packages to install into the container to have a Xserver?
- I guess in my Dockerfile will be needed the display environment var like `ENV DISPLAY=:0`. Is this correct?
- Is anything else needed to be added in `docker run` command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install and run a `x11vnc` inside your docker container. I'll show you how to make it running on a headless host and connect it remotely to run X applications(e.g. xterm).

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM joprovost/docker-x11vnc

RUN mkdir ~/.vnc && touch ~/.vnc/passwd
RUN x11vnc -storepasswd "vncdocker" ~/.vnc/passwd
EXPOSE 5900
CMD ["/usr/bin/x11vnc", "-forever", "-usepw", "-create"]
```

And build a `docker image` named `vnc`:

```
docker build -t vnc .
```

Run a container and remember map port `5900` to host for remote connect(I'm using `--net=host` here):

```
docker run -d --name=vnc --net=host vnc
```

Now you have a running container with `x11vnc` inside, download a vnc client like [realvnc](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) and try to connect to `<server_ip>:5900` from local, the password is `vncdocker` which is set in `Dockerfile`, you'll come to the remote X screen with an `xterm` open. If you execute `env` and will find the environment variable `DISPLAY=:20`

Let's go to the docker container and try to open another `xterm`:

```
docker exec -it vnc bash
```

Then execute the following command inside container:

```
DISPLAY=:20 xterm
```

A new xterm window will popup in your `vnc client` window. I guess that's the way you are going to run your application.

**Note**:

- The base vnc image is based on `ubuntu 14`, but I guess the package is similar in `ubuntu 16`
- Don't expose 5900 if you don't want remote connection

Hope this can help :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot – this just helped me run a KiCad script headless in a Docker image by running it with `xvfb-run` inside the container. It would otherwise complain about missing display.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster please look on one more approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75271849/3153739 , there's also volume specifics and `init: True` next to DISPLAY param.