# Docker with vnc or vagrant with vnc for graphical aplications

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, vnc, vnc-server

I need to initiate Docker (recommended) or vagrant virtual machine on server which I could connect with VNC and in which I would run OBS application for streaming live video (from file or browser view).

I managed to run chrome with VNC in docker container, but I can't do it with OBS. Is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: what is OBS? can you elaborate?

Comment: OBS is Open Broadcaster Software

Comment: https://obsproject.com/download

Comment: There is obs project image which is working in local - https://hub.docker.com/r/spoon4/docker-obs/, but i need to work on remote server and access to it via VNC.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you should add `EXPOSE xxx` in the Dockerfile, and launch it with `docker run -p exposed_port...`

Comment: It is complicated than that. Of course i will expose port for vnc server, but OBS application wont work because it dont gets display and reports graphic card error.

Comment: try `docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/developer/.Xauthority -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro --net=host` which mounts the X11 socket

Comment: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Comment: read http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container