# How to run docker image in ubuntu with vnc?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vnc

In order to examine selenium tests running inside a docker image I am trying to set up a VNC to verify what is going on during the tests.

I am following the suggestions made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container) and created a new docker image with the following additional lines in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN     apt-get install -y x11vnc 
RUN     mkdir ~/.vnc
RUN     x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Then I started the docker image with the following command:

```
docker run -p 5900 --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash selenium-tests
```

and started `krdc` as my VNC viewer. So now what?

I do not see my docker image in `krdc`. Maybe I am missing something? Do I have to start the vnc code inside docker explicitly? Do I need to pass additional arguments to the `docker` command?

- docker: 1.13.1
- ubuntu: 16.4.03
- krdc: 4.14.16

Comment: Hey, if you only want to run Selenium, maybe you can use this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome

Answer (score 17):

There are two issues in the question that prevent you from the goal you want to achieve:

**1.** X server is missed in the image.

**2.** VNC server should be started in a container.

The additional part of `Dockerfile` is:

```
RUN apt-get install -y x11vnc xvfb 
RUN mkdir ~/.vnc
RUN x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

where `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc -forever -usepw -create &
/bin/bash
```

Now we can start a container using the following command:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 5900:5900 <image_name_or_id>
```

and access it via `vncviewer` from the same host where container is started:

```
vncviewer localhost:5900
```

Comment: Don't you need to set the executable bit on entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Yes, executable bit should be set on `entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: I don't see why a shell script is needed here... seems like unnecessary over-enginerring because of < insert reason > 

Just make it 

```ENTRYPOINT x11vnc -forever -usepw -create & /bin/bash```

Keep is simple