# running Puppeteer headfull (headless false) inside docker

Tags: docker, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I need to launch Puppeteer headfull (headless false) inside docker with Chrome and I get the same error: "can't launch chrome".

I install all dependencies but it's falls anytime

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:339:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:329:60)
    at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends tightvncserver xfce4 xfce4-goodies apt-utils gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget x11vnc x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps xvfb apt-utils openvpn fping nano

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Install Chrome
#RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
#RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Disable puppeteer chromium installation
#ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install Puppeteer under /node_modules so it's available system-wide
ADD package.json package-lock.json /
RUN npm install

# Start server on port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Start script on Xvfb
CMD xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" npm start

# VNC Server
CMD vncserver
CMD nc localhost 5901
CMD export DISPLAY=:1
CMD xhost +

# Running app
CMD node app.js
```

Comment: app.js

    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    (async () => {
     try{
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       args: [
        '--disable-features=site-per-process',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
              ],
              headless: false,
              slowMo: 150
      })
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.setViewport({width: 1474, height: 763})
      await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')
     }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
     }
    })()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue in executing puppeteer in headful mode in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667599/issue-in-executing-puppeteer-in-headful-mode-in-docker)