# How can I disable webRTC local IP leak with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I tried:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--enable-webrtc-stun-origin=false', '--enforce-webrtc-ip-permission-check=false']});
```

But this is not working. 
Next I tried:

```
const targets = await browser.targets();
const backgroundPageTarget = targets.find(target => target.type() === 'background_page');
const backgroundPage = await backgroundPageTarget.page();
await backgroundPage.evaluateevaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
  chrome.privacy.network.webRTCIPHandlingPolicy.set({
    value: "default_public_interface_only"
  });
});
```

But got:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined

EDIT: Need solution for {headless: true}.

Comment: you might want to explain your problem...

Comment: Check my answer, test it out, mark as accepted or comment further problems. :) Peace!

Comment: Thx for help, Md. Abu Taher ! Your solution works great! But, Sorry I did not indicate that I need a solution for {headless: true}. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are steps to prevent webrtc IP leak on puppeteer `version 1.9.0`.

### Note:

- Background Pages are available for chrome extensions. You won't probably find a background page on a headless browser.
- Chrome headless does not support extensions. We must use `headless: false`.

### Solution: [WebRTC Leak Prevent](https://github.com/aghorler/WebRTC-Leak-Prevent)

Clone the git repo to some local folder (ie: `extensions/webrtc`),

```
git clone https://github.com/aghorler/WebRTC-Leak-Prevent extensions/webrtc
```

Use it inside your code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function helloWorld() {
  // load the extension
  const extensionPath = 'extensions/webrtc';
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // must be non-headless
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
      `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // test it with browserleaks.com
  await page.goto('https://browserleaks.com/webrtc');

  // psss: just me hiding my details
  await page.evaluate(() => $('#rtc-ipv4 a').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(5px)'));

  // taking evidence
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshots/browserleaks.png' });

  await browser.close();
}

helloWorld();
```

## Result:

[image]

## Advanced Stuff

If you want to quickly hide both Public and Private IP from webRTC, modify this (`extensions/webrtc/background.js`) line to `disable_non_proxied_udp`,

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Solution works fine, but ...... headless: false =((! Do you have any solutions for headless: true pls?Or some links for read =).

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can try with xvfb though. Is that okay, I'll share some resources if you need? Also mark as accepted if the solution works fine. ;)

Comment: Ok, marked. Yes, share pls i need all info =). Maybe you know how to re-compile chromium without #if BUILDFLAG(ENABLE_WEBRTC) and also spoof system time? Some resources, it would be nice! Sorry for my English.

Comment: Building chromium takes a lot of time. I wonder why headless is a must.

Comment: Look at these answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683309/6161265 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020614/6161265

Comment: Ok, thx for great resources! I will try headful than! Maybe you can help me with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027538/how-to-set-change-or-block-timezonesystemtime-with-puppeteer .  Thank you in advance for the great help =).

Comment: I've updated this answer and also provided answer to that question.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher How to use extensions on windows puppeteer ?

Comment: icompatible chromium version

Comment: not works when test in https://proxy6.net/en/privacy

Comment: The answer was working like 6-7 years ago, and will need an update for sure. Things have changed a bit. Puppeteer was version 1, but now puppeteer is version 22.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution without installing any extensions, you can launch Chrome/Chromium with these flags and there will be no IP leak:

```
args: [
  '--webrtc-ip-handling-policy=disable_non_proxied_udp',
  '--force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy',
]
```

Full answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088496/15130822

Comment: this should be accepted answer.
below not update and not workings