# How to set, change or block timezone(systemtime) with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

- OS: Windows 10 Pro x64-based PC
- node -v: v8.12.0
- npm list puppeteer: `-- puppeteer@1.9.0

I tried this:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  env: {
    TZ: 'Australia/Melbourne',
    ...process.env
  }
});
```

Dont work for me. whoer.net sees my actual systemtime.

EDIT: Some information about  https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4230

> This code works well on Linux but does not work on Windows:

```
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';

console.log(new Date());
```

> On Windows, I see timezone from my OS.

Comment: Where do you live? Surely it's not close to `Australia/Melbourne`?

Comment: No =), this code from here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3325#issuecomment-429685007 I'm from Mogilev/Belarus.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution for that I think because it's a OS bug. Almost all solutions mentions it would change the OS timezone directly on windows.

Comment: Its ok I marked your solution, thanks for helping me. I will try some extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-timezone-time-shif/nbofeaabhknfdcpoddmfckpokmncimpj .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide that info for all website, you must use combination of different settings. This is not limited to,

- Proxies
- Location
- Timezone
- WebRTC leak

Because every website will have their own method of finding out. Just changing timezone does not mean the website will think you are from somewhere else.

However, the following code worked perfectly for me.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function timeZoneChecker({ timeZone }) {
  // all kind of config to pass to browser
  const launchConfig = {};

  if (timeZone) {
    launchConfig.env = {
      TZ: timeZone,
      ...process.env,
    };
  }
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchConfig);
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://whoer.net/');
  const detectedTimezone = await page.$eval('.ico-timesystem', e => e.parentNode.innerText);
  await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshots/timeZone_${timeZone.replace('/', '-')}.png`, fullPage: true });

  await browser.close();

  return { timeZone, detectedTimezone };
}

Promise.all([
  timeZoneChecker({ timeZone: 'Australia/Melbourne' }),
  timeZoneChecker({ timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore' }),
]).then(console.log);
```

Result:

```
➜  change-timezone node app/timezone.js
[ { timeZone: 'Australia/Melbourne',
    detectedTimezone: 'Sun Oct 28 2018 22:44:35 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)' },
  { timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore',
    detectedTimezone: 'Sun Oct 28 2018 19:44:36 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)' } ]
```

Comment: Thx!  But it's not working. Mayby because my OS is Win 10? I found some information about issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4230 , but its still open =( Sorry, again I didn’t give enough detail in my question.

Comment: @KisaGut Yes you are correct on windows it is not working. I tested on linux and timezone code from accepted solution works fine.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md), you can use [`page.emulateTimezone()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageemulatetimezonetimezoneid):

> #### page.emulateTimezone()
>
> `timezoneId` <?[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> Changes the timezone of the page. See [ICU’s metaZones.txt](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/icu/source/data/misc/metaZones.txt?rcl=faee8bc70570192d82d2978a71e2a615788597d1) for a list of supported timezone IDs. Passing `null` disables timezone emulation.
>
> returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)>

For example:

```
await page.emulateTimezone('America/Chicago');
```

Comment: how to use this with typescript? this function is not available for me