# Javascript Date() returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Hi the date today is 2020 10th of November. So it should look something like this `2020-11-10`

Also, the time now is 7:15 AM

When I run this code:

```
var d1 = new Date()
console.log(d1)
```

It outputs this

```
2020-11-09T23:15:16.226Z
```

Notice how the day and the hour is wrong.

However, if I run these codes:

```
console.log( d1.getDate() )
console.log( d1.getHour() )
```

It outputs the correct values. I have no idea what is going on.

Can someone please explain what's the issue? does it has something to do with time zones?

Comment: `.###Z` <= the `Z` on the end without a + or - means it is without the timezone and is for UTC

Comment: @Taplar how do I set the time zone ? Mine is GMT +8

Comment: `new Date()` should by default already be using your timezone.  So it is a little strange that you are saying you do not see that.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @Taplar I'm running NodeJs Puppeteer. I'm calling the function from my puppeteer browser instances.

Comment: K, I've added those relevant tags to the question to try to get more experienced eyes on it.

Comment: @Taplar Thank u! I would also like to add that when I execute the commands on chrome console. I get the following `Tue Nov 10 2020 07:26:44 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)` which is accurate :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set, change or block timezone(systemtime) with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027538/how-to-set-change-or-block-timezonesystemtime-with-puppeteer)

Comment: @Axiumin_ Hi thanks for the feedback! but sadly nope :( I still get `2020-11-09T23:30:21.385Z` after I added `await page.emulateTimezone("Asia/Singapore");` to puppeteer.