# How to Disable WebRTC chromium source code

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I am trying to disable webrtc to protect ip address from leaking in chromium , is there any way to disable it ?

Comment: Yes you . When I go to https://browserleaks.com/webrtc is there any way to disable my ip

Comment: You can use certain switches to disable certain webrtc features: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @asesh I tried replacing --force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy = default_public_interface_only , but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can control WebRTC traffic using Google's official extension [WebRTC Network Limiter](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/webrtc-network-limiter/npeicpdbkakmehahjeeohfdhnlpdklia).

After being installed, you need to configure it from settings (screenshot below).

**Alternatively**, you can launch Chrome/Chromium from the terminal using these flags:

```
--webrtc-ip-handling-policy=disable_non_proxied_udp
--force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy
```

[image]