# How to run google chrome headless in docker? using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, puppeteer, docker-container

when i Headless:false that Time to Fetch this Error Project running inside docker

I need to launch Puppeteer headfull (headless false) inside docker with Chrome and I get the same error: "can't launch chrome".

I install This dependencies but Not Working headless False

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.12
RUN apk --update add bash curl findutils
# Installs latest Chromium (89) package.
RUN apk add --no-cache chromium nss freetype freetype-dev harfbuzz ca-certificates ttf-freefont nodejs yarn

# Tell Puppeteer to skip installing Chrome. We'll be using the installed package.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Puppeteer v6.0.0 works with Chromium 89.
RUN yarn add puppeteer@6.0.0


RUN npm i -g npm
RUN npm install pm2 -g
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY ./package.json /usr/app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /usr/app/
COPY ./config/config.docker.json ./config/config.json
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/logs/
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

And when i run That Time to Fetch this Error Failed to launch the browser process!

```
2022-03-28 11:37:18: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2|web-script-workers  | [349:349:0328/113718.390886:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.
2|web-script-workers  | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
2|web-script-workers  |     at onClose (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:237:20)
2|web-script-workers  |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:228:79)
2|web-script-workers  |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:412:35)
2|web-script-workers  |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
2|web-script-workers  | 2022-03-28 11:37:18: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2|web-script-workers  | [349:349:0328/113718.390886:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.
2|web-script-workers  | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
2|web-script-workers  |     at onClose (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:237:20)
2|web-script-workers  |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:228:79)
2|web-script-workers  |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:412:35)
2|web-script-workers  |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
2|web-script-workers  | 2022-03-28 11:37:18: return
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue in executing puppeteer in headful mode in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667599/issue-in-executing-puppeteer-in-headful-mode-in-docker)