# unable to view the playwright docker test execution through VNC viewer

Tags: playwright, vnc-viewer, playwright-test

I am trying to execute the script in mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic docker container .

I have exposed the port 5900 as shown below but unable to connect to host when i tried with the vnc viewer localhost:5900. I can able to view other docker container such as selenium/standalone-chrome execution through vnc viewer but not playwright !

How can I view the playwright docker container test execution ?  is any other  way that i can see the test execution live ? Any help would be much appreciated !

```
 docker run --name playwright1 -it --rm --ipc=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -u root -p 5900:5900 -v $(pwd):/src -v /home/Automation/:/root/.m2 mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic  &
```

Answer (score 1):

You have exposed the port, but is a vnc server & x-server like Xvfb running inside the container? Opening the port won't accomplish anything if there isn't anything listening on the other side.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377744/how-to-run-docker-image-in-ubuntu-with-vnc/49426599#49426599) question has great information on how to setup both `xvfb` and `x11vnc` to achieve what you are trying to do. Just add `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal` to the top of your own Dockerfile, followed by the stuff in the linked answer.