# How to dockerize an app together with VNC (arduino IDE)

Tags: docker

I'm trying to dockerize an arduino IDE on raspberry pi using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311264/6791424

*ps: I know how to pass the X server to the docker container but in this case I really need VNC*

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y arduino x11vnc xvfb

RUN mkdir ~/.vnc && x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd

CMD x11vnc -forever -usepw -create & /usr/bin/arduino
```

Here's the output of `docker run -p 5900 arduino_docker`:

```
05/04/2018 08:22:10 -usepw: found /root/.vnc/passwd
05/04/2018 08:22:10 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 11
05/04/2018 08:22:10 
05/04/2018 08:22:10 wait_for_client: WAIT:cmd=FINDCREATEDISPLAY-Xvfb
05/04/2018 08:22:10 
05/04/2018 08:22:10 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/2560
05/04/2018 08:22:10 
05/04/2018 08:22:10 Autoprobing TCP port 
05/04/2018 08:22:10 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
05/04/2018 08:22:10 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
05/04/2018 08:22:10 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
05/04/2018 08:22:10 listen6: bind: Address already in use
05/04/2018 08:22:10 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
05/04/2018 08:22:10 

The VNC desktop is:      1843fd6c8bdd:0
PORT=5900
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Preferences.save(Preferences.java:735)
    at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:249)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:117)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:234)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

As you can see, the vnc server is working. However, the arduino IDE tries to access the DISPLAY env variable but can't find it. I even tried adding `ENV DISPLAY 0` in the Dockerfile but then it complains of not being able to access that display.

**UPDATE**: by doing some research on xvfb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#Remote_control_over_SSH

I changed the dockerfile to:

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y arduino x11vnc xvfb

RUN mkdir ~/.vnc && x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd

ENV DISPLAY :1

CMD /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1366x768x16 & x11vnc -display :1 -forever -usepw -create & /usr/bin/arduino
```

Now it connects but the screen is black.

Here's the output:

```
05/04/2018 11:30:21 -usepw: found /root/.vnc/passwd
05/04/2018 11:30:21 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 12
05/04/2018 11:30:21 
05/04/2018 11:30:21 wait_for_client: WAIT:cmd=FINDCREATEDISPLAY-Xvfb
05/04/2018 11:30:21 
05/04/2018 11:30:21 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/2560
05/04/2018 11:30:21 
05/04/2018 11:30:21 Autoprobing TCP port 
05/04/2018 11:30:21 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
05/04/2018 11:30:21 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
05/04/2018 11:30:21 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
05/04/2018 11:30:21 listen6: bind: Address already in use
05/04/2018 11:30:21 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
05/04/2018 11:30:21 

The VNC desktop is:      f6627eb9da23:0
PORT=5900
05/04/2018 11:30:34 Got connection from client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:34   other clients:
05/04/2018 11:30:34 Normal socket connection
05/04/2018 11:30:34 incr accepted_client=1 for 172.17.0.1:58432  sock=6
05/04/2018 11:30:34 wait_for_client: got client
05/04/2018 11:30:34 Client Protocol Version 3.8
05/04/2018 11:30:34 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
05/04/2018 11:30:34 client progressed=1 in 3/4 0.033597 s
05/04/2018 11:30:34 client useCopyRect: 172.17.0.1 0
05/04/2018 11:30:34 client_set_net: 172.17.0.1  0.1224
05/04/2018 11:30:34 wait_for_client: running: env X11VNC_SKIP_DISPLAY=''  /bin/sh /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 1: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: netstat: not found
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 1: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: xauth: not found
05/04/2018 11:30:35 wait_for_client: find display cmd failed.
05/04/2018 11:30:35 wait_for_client: FINDCREATEDISPLAY cmd: /bin/sh /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT Xvfb
trying N=20 ...
redir_daemon=
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 461: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 461: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: nmerge: not found
-f: not found
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 462: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: nmerge: not found
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 462: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: -f: not found
/usr/bin/Xvfb :20 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -cc 4 -nolisten tcp -auth  
use: X [:<display>] [option]
-a #                   default pointer acceleration (factor)
-ac                    disable access control restrictions
-audit int             set audit trail level
-auth file             select authorization file
-br                    create root window with black background
+bs                    enable any backing store support
-bs                    disable any backing store support
-c                     turns off key-click
c #                    key-click volume (0-100)
-cc int                default color visual class
-nocursor              disable the cursor
-core                  generate core dump on fatal error
-displayfd fd          file descriptor to write display number to when ready to connect
-dpi int               screen resolution in dots per inch
-dpms                  disables VESA DPMS monitor control
-deferglyphs [none|all|16] defer loading of [no|all|16-bit] glyphs
-f #                   bell base (0-100)
-fc string             cursor font
-fn string             default font name
-fp string             default font path
-help                  prints message with these options
+iglx                  Allow creating indirect GLX contexts
-iglx                  Prohibit creating indirect GLX contexts (default)
-I                     ignore all remaining arguments
-ld int                limit data space to N Kb
-lf int                limit number of open files to N
-ls int                limit stack space to N Kb
-nolock                disable the locking mechanism
-maxclients n          set maximum number of clients (power of two)
-nolisten string       don't listen on protocol
-listen string         listen on protocol
-noreset               don't reset after last client exists
-background [none]     create root window with no background
-reset                 reset after last client exists
-p #                   screen-saver pattern duration (minutes)
-pn                    accept failure to listen on all ports
-nopn                  reject failure to listen on all ports
-r                     turns off auto-repeat
r                      turns on auto-repeat 
-render [default|mono|gray|color] set render color alloc policy
-retro                 start with classic stipple and cursor
-s #                   screen-saver timeout (minutes)
-seat string           seat to run on
-t #                   default pointer threshold (pixels/t)
-terminate             terminate at server reset
-to #                  connection time out
-tst                   disable testing extensions
ttyxx                  server started from init on /dev/ttyxx
v                      video blanking for screen-saver
-v                     screen-saver without video blanking
-wm                    WhenMapped default backing-store
-wr                    create root window with white background
-maxbigreqsize         set maximal bigrequest size 
+xinerama              Enable XINERAMA extension
-xinerama              Disable XINERAMA extension
-dumbSched             Disable smart scheduling, enable old behavior
-schedInterval int     Set scheduler interval in msec
-sigstop               Enable SIGSTOP based startup
+extension name        Enable extension
-extension name        Disable extension
-query host-name       contact named host for XDMCP
-broadcast             broadcast for XDMCP
-multicast [addr [hops]] IPv6 multicast for XDMCP
-indirect host-name    contact named host for indirect XDMCP
-port port-num         UDP port number to send messages to
-from local-address    specify the local address to connect from
-once                  Terminate server after one session
-class display-class   specify display class to send in manage
-cookie xdm-auth-bits  specify the magic cookie for XDMCP
-displayID display-id  manufacturer display ID for request
[+-]accessx [ timeout [ timeout_mask [ feedback [ options_mask] ] ] ]
                       enable/disable accessx key sequences
-ardelay               set XKB autorepeat delay
-arinterval            set XKB autorepeat interval
-screen scrn WxHxD     set screen's width, height, depth
-pixdepths list-of-int support given pixmap depths
+/-render          turn on/off RENDER extension support(default on)
-linebias n            adjust thin line pixelization
-blackpixel n          pixel value for black
-whitepixel n          pixel value for white
-fbdir directory       put framebuffers in mmap'ed files in directory
-shmem                 put framebuffers in shared memory
/usr/bin/nohup: failed to run command ‘.xinitrc’: No such file or directory
/tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: 981: /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.QuzQwT: -f: not found
05/04/2018 11:30:43 Using X display :20
05/04/2018 11:30:43 rootwin: 0x43 reswin: 0x200001 dpy: 0x109a8b8
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:43 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
05/04/2018 11:30:43 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:43   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
05/04/2018 11:30:43   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
05/04/2018 11:30:43   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
05/04/2018 11:30:43   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:43 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
05/04/2018 11:30:43   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
05/04/2018 11:30:43    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
05/04/2018 11:30:43    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
05/04/2018 11:30:43      moved window is released in the new position.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
05/04/2018 11:30:43   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
05/04/2018 11:30:43   periodic repaints.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:43 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
05/04/2018 11:30:43   to: '-cursor most'.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
05/04/2018 11:30:43   or '-noxfixes'.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 GrabServer control via XTEST.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:43 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
05/04/2018 11:30:43   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
05/04/2018 11:30:43   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
05/04/2018 11:30:43   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
05/04/2018 11:30:43   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
05/04/2018 11:30:43   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
05/04/2018 11:30:43   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
05/04/2018 11:30:43   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
05/04/2018 11:30:43   periodic repaints.
05/04/2018 11:30:43 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
05/04/2018 11:30:44   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
05/04/2018 11:30:44   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
05/04/2018 11:30:44   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
05/04/2018 11:30:44   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
05/04/2018 11:30:44   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 X FBPM extension not supported.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 X display is not capable of DPMS.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 --------------------------------------------------------
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Default visual ID: 0x21
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/5120
05/04/2018 11:30:44 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x108b6c0, 0x0, 1280, 1024, 8, 1, 4)
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Pixel format for client 172.17.0.1:
05/04/2018 11:30:44   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
05/04/2018 11:30:44   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 X display :20 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 calling setTranslateFunction()...
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Pixel format for client 172.17.0.1:
05/04/2018 11:30:44   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
05/04/2018 11:30:44   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
05/04/2018 11:30:44 no translation needed
05/04/2018 11:30:44   done.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 TS_REDIR is empty, restarting...
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
05/04/2018 11:30:44 
05/04/2018 11:30:44 fb read rate: 58 MB/sec
05/04/2018 11:30:44 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
05/04/2018 11:30:44 screen setup finished.
PORT=5900
05/04/2018 11:30:44 

The VNC desktop is:      f6627eb9da23:0

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching

05/04/2018 11:30:44 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Battling with something for -norepeat!! (1 resets left)
05/04/2018 11:30:44 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
05/04/2018 11:30:44   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (2 times)
05/04/2018 11:30:44 created   xdamage object: 0x20002c
05/04/2018 11:30:50 cutbuffer_send: no send: uninitialized clients
05/04/2018 11:30:57 client useCopyRect: 172.17.0.1 0
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Pixel format for client 172.17.0.1:
05/04/2018 11:30:57   8 bpp, depth 8
05/04/2018 11:30:57   true colour: max r 7 g 7 b 3, shift r 0 g 3 b 6
05/04/2018 11:30:57 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type ultraZip
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Using compression level 9 for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Using image quality level 0 for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Using JPEG subsampling 1, Q15 for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling cursor position updates for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling KeyboardLedState protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling SupportedMessages protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling SupportedEncodings protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling ServerIdentity protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Enabling Xvp protocol extension for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:30:57 Using tight encoding for client 172.17.0.1
05/04/2018 11:31:30 created selwin: 0x20002d
05/04/2018 11:31:30 called initialize_xfixes()
```

Comment: is that address already in use? `listen6: bind: Address already in use`

Comment: @hichamx for ipv6 yes, but I don't know which address

Comment: on the host run `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and the docker run command should lokk like `docker run -d -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY ....`

Comment: @hichamx I think I forgot to mention that the raspberry is a server, it has no graphics, so probably no display. And what's the point of setting the DISPLAY env if I'm overriding it in the command? Thanks

Comment: Just for more clarification, what is the OS where docker is installed?

Comment: @hichamx raspbian Version: March 2018

Comment: well respbian has a GUI which will be used to display the arduino IDE

Comment: @hichamx but it s the server version, and I just want to access it through network. And how it's going to appear in the raspbian GUI? I'm just passing the environment variable

Comment: if you are in Machine A, and you want to access Machine B where raspbian and docker are installed, you have to maintain two accesses: from A to B and from B to the container.

Comment: @hichamx technicaly if I run a VNC server inside the container then I don't see why the outside machine matters. Shouldn't I be able to connect directly to it?

Comment: @hichamx see my update

Comment: Could you change the permissions of `/home/user/.vnc/xstartup` to 755

Comment: @hichamx there's no such file. And the user inside the container is root so permissions shouldn't be a problem