# GUI in docker application

Tags: docker, gtk

I have a desktop application written completely in C with GUI written in Gtk. Currently, it works fine on my Ubuntu desktop.

Now, I want to use the application independent of the OS. Therefore, Docker seems to help with it but as far as I know, it only provides web based UI.

How can I use Docker to deploy standalone desktop applications?

Is there any other container which does the job?

P.S.: The application is written in Gtk 2 hence I cannot use broadway.

Comment: Have a look at [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/39681017#39681017.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself anytime but just suggesting what might seem obvious.

You can try this though:

- Run XVNC server inside the container
- Expose the port at which XVNC runs
- Connect to the XVNC server from the host machine
- Trigger your gui application from within the XVNC console