# Run any kind of browser on Raspberry pi 3 without GUI

Tags: browser, raspberry-pi3, remote-access, tunneling

The goal is to open a web browser in my home network from a from a remote location with ssh tunnelling.
SSH tunnel is okay, I just want to somehow run a browser on my RPI3 in my home network.

Is it possible somehow?

I use my pi as a media server, only kodi is running on it, there isn't any GUI operating system on it (raspbian for example).

All kind of solution is interested.

Comment: Exactly the one that you've written. I want to open eg. a firefox webbrowser running on my pi at my home network and login to a local network device website. I know I can do it with tunnelling, but I want to open locally on that device. Maybe I should run a docker for firefox and create a tunnel to there like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container#

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it is not clear. Let's give another try. Raspberry pi 3, no gui, however I want to  run somehow a browser on it. How? From the office I create a tunnel to my pi at home and open a firefox from my pi on my office computer which has GUI and on my office computer type to the browser which is running on my pi like 192.168.1.123. So let's say forward the GUI to my office computer but the browser running in my local  network.

Comment: This one works, now need to figure out how to install docker on RPI3. I tested with centos without gui and it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container#

Comment: Based on this article my issue solved. [Can you run GUI applications in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container#)

Comment: I just cam across here and this was the last article i've read:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/why-is-my-simple-html-canvas-rendering-only-11fps-in-chromium-a-pi3
You do have a solution now but this guy just had it running. He says `I do not have a desktop environment and I am running chrome directly`.
So he basically has 5 lines of code followed by `startx` command and it works :=)
So if you want a smart solution, search for `startx` in the question and you see code which does exactly what you want.