# Error when run docker images in raspberry pi

Tags: docker, firefox, raspberry-pi, x11, xauth

I managed to run this firefox docker container on a standard linux box based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container#), however when I installed docker on my raspberry pi, I get this error when I want to run the same:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec format error".
```

I've followed the instruction of a guy in the discussion:

```
Windows 7+

It's a bit easier on Windows 7+ with MobaXterm:

    Install MobaXterm for windows
    Start MobaXterm
    Configure X server: Settings -> X11 (tab) -> set X11 Remote Access to full
    Use this BASH script to launch the container

run_docker.bash:

#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONTAINER=py3:2016-03-23-rc3
COMMAND=/bin/bash
DISPLAY="$(hostname):0"
USER=$(whoami)

docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    --user=$USER \
    --workdir="/home/$USER" \
    -v "/c/Users/$USER:/home/$USER:rw" \
    -e DISPLAY \
    $CONTAINER \
    $COMMAND
```

On my pi this is the start script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONTAINER=creack/firefox-vnc
COMMAND=/bin/bash
#DISPLAY="$(hostname):1.0"
DISPLAY="CCKK4H2:0.0"
USER=$(whoami)

docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    --user=$USER \
    --workdir="/home/$USER" \
    -v "/c/Users/$USER:/home/$USER:rw" \
    -e DISPLAY \
    $CONTAINER \
    $COMMAND
```

This is how it worked for me on normal centos.

Any idea how to troubleshoot or what does this means?

Answer (score 0):

On Raspberry PI, you can only run images designed to work on ARM architectures.

You can find some in the `arm32v*` repositories : [`arm32v6`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v6/) or [`arm32v7`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/).

If you want to create your own ARM compatible images, you must build the images from an ARM device (your Raspberry PI for example).