# Using X11 to run GUI apps inside docker not working

Tags: docker, x11, x11-forwarding

I am trying to run a GUI app inside docker container using X11 forwarding and am not able to get it to work even when binding Xauthority file.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add xterm
RUN adduser --disabled-password --home /home/user --uid 1000 --gecos 'USER' user
WORKDIR /home/user
USER user

CMD /usr/bin/xterm
```

I have tried the following commands to run, and none have been successful:

```
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY image
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix image
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY -v $XAUTHORITY image
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY -v $XAUTHORITY -v /tmp/.X11-unix image
docker run -it --rm --net=host --privileged -e DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY -v $XAUTHORITY -v /tmp/.X11-unix image
```

Basically, they all produce the same error `Can't open display: :0`. At this point, I have run out of all options discussed at StackOverflow and other tutorials

I am not sure if the permissions on the Xauthority file is important, but when I bind, from inside the container, it has `root:root` permissions where the host has `user:user` permissions.

I have also used ([Can you run GUI applications in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container?rq=1)) but have not had any success with the answers

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/) post specifically the GUI section. The developer is|was at Docker and a proponent of showing how to run most everything under Docker. HTH!

Comment: I have used those images also but I have the same issue with them. I have used the UNIX socket and display variable set to unix:0, but I still get the same error

Comment: Ah, I'm outta ideas, sorry.

Comment: I tried adding 755 permissions on host for XAUTHORITY file and am able to connect, but this requires --privileged tag. Do you have any suggestions which does not require --privileged

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `xhost +` prior to running your container (so your local X server will accept connections from the container)? You'll still need to set DISPLAY etc. something like this:

`docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e "DISPLAY=unix:0.0" --device /dev/dri --privileged -it --rm yourapp`

Note: `xhost +` allows incoming X connections from *anywhere*, so be careful with that!

Comment: Can also run `xhost -` after the docker container is finished...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).