# Run GUI app in linux docker on linux server on windows host

Tags: linux, windows, docker, pycharm, x11

The following system was built (not by me):

Windows 10 operating system is installed on the local machine.
Connection goes to the remote server with Ubuntu 16.04 through a client (like SmarTTY or Bitwise SSH Client).
The docker container is launched on the server.

How do I configure the system so that the GUI application can be started from the container on the remote server and I can interact with it?

I don't quite understand the ports and DISPLAY values system.

With smarTTY and its vcxsrv client I can run this application outside the container, but not inside - there are errors about missing some java files.

EDIT: Adding reports and more information
I have this configuration of running command for docker:

```
docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia -it --name delobo \
-v /opt/pycharm-community-2019.1.3/:/opt/pycharm/  -v $(pwd):/workspace \
-v /media/:/media/ \
-v /home/boyko/.Xauthority:/home/boyko/.Xauthority \
-e XAUTHORITY=/home/boyko/.Xauthority \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw --privileged \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v $HOME/:/home/boyko \
--network=host tensorflow_me bash
```

and all this time when i was trying to run GUI of PyCharm, i get something like this:

```
Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:78)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:75)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/pycharm/jre64/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:172)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:107)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
        ... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:158)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:134)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.processException(PluginManager.java:140)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$1.uncaughtException(PluginManager.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea how to repair this issue.

**Must note there, that if we use Linux as main local machine (instead of using Windows, as i have to), there is no errors, and PyCharm runs normally.**

Comment: please add some logs, you are getting. information is not complete to answer.

Comment: I think this is what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container

Comment: @F.Kam thank you for link, but unfortunately there is no working solution for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this way: i need to install these packages inside my container under root:

`apt-get install libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6`

So now i have pycharm displayed and it's interacting well.

The main tip was written and described [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di/826946)