# No protocol specified : cannot connect to X server

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to create a docker image with opencv in order to display a video. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ADD testDocker_1.py /
ADD video1.mp4 /
RUN pip install opencv-python
CMD [ "python", "./testDocker_1.py" ]
```

And the following python script:

```
import cv2
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = './video1.mp4'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('Frame Docker', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

So first I build the Image:

```
$ sudo docker build -t test1 .
```

And the problem comes when I run the container:

```
$ sudo docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix test1
No protocol specified
: cannot connect to X server :1
```

Regards.

Comment: As you've already noticed, getting a Docker container to connect to your host display is awkward at best; Docker really isn't designed for this use case.  Why do you want it the program (with access to host hardware devices) to run inside a container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
xhost +
sudo docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix test1
```

Although it would solve this particular use case, but you need to make a note of the following:

> **Basically, the xhost + allows everybody to use your host x server;**

[Refrence](https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/30/docker-image-with-opencv-with-x11-forwarding-for-gui/)

A better and recommended solution is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/)

Comment: `xhost +` allows unrestricted access to your display server to anyone who can reach it.  That includes capturing and injecting keystrokes.  You almost certainly don't want to do this.