# How to setup OpenDJ as an external Identity Store/Repository for OpenAM?

Tags: identity, openam, opendj, forgerock

How do you set up the LDAPv3 compliant directory service [OpenDJ](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenDJ) as an external Identity store for the Access Management solution [OpenAM](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM)?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This answer is only supposed to serve as a starting point as I could not find any good information on the subject after two days of digging. As Bernhard pointed out in the comments, you e.g. should not use the user RootDN in production.*

1. Start both services using docker:

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  openam:
    image: openidentityplatform/openam
    container_name: am
    hostname: openam.example.com
    network_mode: host
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
  opendj:
    image: openidentityplatform/opendj
    container_name: dj
    hostname: cts.example.com
    network_mode: host
    user: root
    ports:
        - 1389:1389
```

2. Add the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost openam.example.com cts.example.com
```

3. Run `docker-compose up -d` within in the folder of the `docker-compose.yml` file.
4. Wait until both services started up. Then run `docker exec -it dj /bin/bash` to start the interactive mode for your OpenDJ container. The OpenDJ image already comes with a preconfigured Identity Store. To retrieve all the relevant information for configuring OpenAM enter the `opendj` folder within the container (`cd opendj`) and run:

```sh
$ bin/status --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword password
```

```sh
          --- Connection Handlers ---
Address:Port : Protocol : State
-------------:----------:---------
--           : LDIF     : Disabled
0.0.0.0:636  : LDAPS    : Disabled
0.0.0.0:1389 : LDAP     : Enabled
0.0.0.0:1689 : JMX      : Disabled
0.0.0.0:8080 : HTTP     : Disabled

          --- Data Sources ---
Base DN:     dc=example,dc=com
Backend ID:  userRoot
Entries:     203
Replication:
```

*For more commands like the above and to configure the server by your self have a look at [OpenDJ's community How To](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenDJ/wiki/How-To).*

5. Open up your browser and go to `http://openam.example.com:8080/openam`. Should you run on a headless VM have a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220126/considering-url-redirections-how-to-use-guis-of-web-applications-running-in-dif) of mine, as I ran into the same problem.
6. Select "Create New Configuration":[image: List item]
7. Accept the terms and click "Continue". When prompted to enter a password for the default user [amAdmin] enter e.g. OpenAM's amAdmin's default password `changeit` and click "next": [image]
8. In the "Server Setting" tab leave everything except the cookie domain. Change the cookie domain to `.example.com` and click "next".[image]
9. Do not change anything in the "Configuration Store" tab and click "next".
10. In the "User Store" tab enter the information from the configured OpenDJ server, the default password `password` of the OpenDJ server, and the directory name `cts.example.com` set in the `docker-compose.yml` file and then click "next":[image]
11. Do not change anything in the "Site Configuration" tab and click "next".
12. In the "Agent Information" tab enter a password (like e.g. `password`) and click next.
13. Check the Summary and click "Create Configuration":[image]
14. Done!

To check your work login to OpenAM as user `amadmin` with the previous set password `changeit`. Then go to `Top Level Realm > Data Store > Subjects`:
[image]
**Careful:** In your case you will only see the user "Admin" and "Anonymous" as you did not populate your identity store yet.

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to specify the external user data store during initial configuration but configure it later on (especially if an LB is frontending the DS). Furhtermore do not use the RootDN as this make OpenAM re-configure the DS, but this is actually the job of the DS administrator and not of OpenAM

Comment: This answer is only supposed to serve as a starting point as I could not find any good information on the subject after two days of digging. However, can you elaborate on why it is not a good idea to specify the external user data store during the initial configuration and what role the LB plays in this case?

Comment: If something goes wrong when talking to the external LDAP DS, then the configuration of OpenAM fails (happens quite often) and you have to start from scratch. When you are using an external configuration data store, this has to be clean up or setup from scratch as well.
When you use the RootDN then OpenAM will (try to) change the configuration of the DS. E.g. when OpenDJ is used, configuration is instance local, so only one instance behind LB is changed and you need to take care to adopt all other instances (this is often forgotten) ....

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official documentation of forgerock directory server, and forgerock AM, its still configured the same way even in the payed version.

[More Here](https://backstage.forgerock.com)