# Fullscreen GUI app from Docker container on Coral Dev Board

Tags: python, docker, wayland, google-coral, mendel-os

I'm trying to run a Python GUI app from a docker container, but when I'm trying to display on fullscreen, nothing shows up. If I'm not calling `cv2.setWindowProperty("frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)`, the windows appears on screen normaly.

This is the Dockerfile used :

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental

FROM arm64v8/debian:latest

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  ca-certificates \
  gnupg \
  curl

RUN echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" \
  | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list \
  && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  python3 \
  python3-pip \
  python3-opencv \
  python3-pycoral \
  zlib1g-dev \
  libjpeg-dev

RUN pip3 install \
  v4l2 \
  screeninfo \
  pillo
```

And this is the script:

```
import cv2
import screeninfo

# Capture video from webcam
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    # Capture each frame of webcam video
    screen = screeninfo.get_monitors()[0]
    cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.moveWindow("frame", screen.x - 1, screen.y - 1)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    # Close and break the loop after pressing "x" key
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("x"):
        break

# close the already opened camera
vid_capture.release()
# close the window and de-allocate any associated memory usage
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm using the following `docker run` command:

```
docker run -d --rm \
  --device /dev/apex_0:/dev/apex_0 \
  --device /dev/video1:/dev/video1 \
  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  guiapp bash
```

Before running the container, I'm making sure that the environment is configured with these:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xhost +
```

I can't think of anything that may cause this strange behaviour.

EDIT: after further investigation, I found out that I face the same problem when logged in as `root`.

Comment: I'm not where I can dig into test anything out right now.. but have you seen this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Yes Matt, and the weirdest thing is that the X11 forwarding WORKS :)), but when I resize the OpenCV window to fullscreen, nothing shows up. I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: man that sucks! maybe try using `xprop` to get the name of the window generated by docker/the app and see if its different than expected. I'm thinking maybe its being prefixed with something. I dunno just a thought.