# GUI application via Docker - X11 - "Unable to init server"

Tags: docker, x11, opensuse, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run Firefox in a Debian docker image but can't connect to the X11 server.

I'm using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280523/2488942), but changed the base image to the latest Debian. I also changed the user creation method.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:latest                                                                 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox-esr
RUN useradd --shell /bin/bash --create-home developer && \
    usermod -aG sudo developer
  
USER developer
ENV HOME /home/developer
CMD /usr/bin/firefox
```

**Building the container**

```
docker build -t firefox .
```

**Command to start the container**

```
docker run -ti --rm \
   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
   firefox
```

**ERROR**

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

**Operating system**

OpenSUSE Leap 15.2

**Context**

I'm doing the above to understand how to run a GUI app via docker. The aim is to run the latest version of FreeCAD (v19), which is currently broken on OpenSUSE.

Comment: If you want to run X11 applications in `docker` / want to learn about the inner workings I can recommend having a look into [`x11docker`](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)!

Comment: @acran Looks great! Will go through this one for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
docker run --rm \
--net=host \
--env="DISPLAY" \
--volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/home/developer/.Xauthority:rw" \
firefox
```

This should work with your Dockerfile!

Couple of points

- .Xauthority file also needs to be shared as it holds the cookies and auth sessions for the X server. Hence it has to be read/write too.
- If you dont want to do `--net=host` then you can listen on a TCP port bound to unix socket and forward that to the container.

Comment: Thanks heaps, it does work indeed! Where can I read more about how this works? I know very little about .Xauthority, etc. Do you have any good resources?