# How do I deploy a Tkinter/GUI App with Docker?

Tags: python, docker, tkinter, x11

I wrote an app in Python with a Tkinter GUI and I am trying to deploying it with Docker. I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to get it to work.

When I tried to run it locally, I got a `"no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"` error.

I poked around found out I could fix that by adding this to my python script:

```
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
```

Now I get `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"`.

I tried adding `-u=$(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER) -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -v $(pwd)/app:/app --rm <app name>` to my launch script (as suggested [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/empowering-docker-using-tkinter-gui-bf076d9e4974)) but this didn't fix anything.

I know this is a question that has been asked more than a few times, but it's an error that comes up a lot, and the problem seems to have a number of solutions across versions and platforms. Thanks.

Comment: [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) has a lot of options (some better and some worse) but it's complicated and not especially portable to non-Linux systems; would it make more sense to run this application directly on the host and not in a container?

Comment: ha yeah i've been down this road unfortunately but thanks ... do you happen to know if there's a way to use a web browser to display a Tkinter app?