# Errro when creating a DockerFile with Node and Eletron

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, electron, dockerfile

I am trying to creating a container with Node + Electron, but the container it's not starting when I run the command

```bash
docker logs idcontainer
```

its showing this error:

```bash
webpack serve --mode development --progress --config  build/webpack.dev.conf.js electron
sh: 1: webpack: not found
```

this is my dockerfile

```compose
FROM node:19-bullseye

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
    git libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxtst6 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libxss1 libasound2 \
    -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /home/app/ && chown -R node:node /home/app/

WORKDIR /home/app/
USER node

COPY . /home/app/

RUN npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
RUN npm install --save-dev electron
RUN npm install install
RUN npx electron-rebuild

USER root

RUN chown root /home/app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
RUN chmod 4755 /home/app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox

USER node
EXPOSE 6665

CMD ["npm", "run"] 

CMD ["npm", "start", "electron"]
```

and this is my docker-compose

```json
version: "3"
services:
    service:
        build: .
        ports:
            - '6665:6665'
        container_name: serviceDesktop
        volumes:
            - .:/home/app
```

to create a new container with Node + Electron

Comment: Running GUI applications in Docker is finicky and non-portable (also see [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) for some of the machinations required).  Especially if you're going to use a bind mount so that the code comes from your host system and not an image, you'll probably find this easier to run from the host.

Comment: The specific error is probably coming from the `volumes:` mount hiding everything the image does, including its `node_modules` tree, and you might try deleting that block from the Compose file.