# Running Docker container - X11 failed to open display :0

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, x11, fyne

I have a project written in Golang using the Fyne framework. I am aware of the issues that are related to X11 when trying to Dockerize these type of applications. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev x11-apps dbus-x11 xvfb make
RUN make

# my Golang app takes in a single command line argument hence the ENTRYPOINT.
# specifically, the command line argument is an address the application will use.
ENTRYPOINT ["./cmd/server/server"]
```

Here is how I am running it:
`docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -p 8080:3000 --net=host red "localhost:3000"`

However, this seems to cause the error:

```
PlatformError: X11: Failed to open display :0
panic: NotInitialized: The GLFW library is not initialized
```

I am also aware of the available `fyne-cross` project. I attempted to use that and ran into more problems as well. I would like to try Dockerize this project myself however.

I've tried doing `xhost + local:docker` (I know, not secure) however the same error pops up.
I have also tried:
`docker run -it   --rm   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix red "localhost:3000"`
I've also tried with and without the `--net=host`. I saw this solution in another post but it didn't seem to do anything. For context, I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: This sounds not unlike [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container); have you run through its various answers?  You do not need `--net=host`, but you do need to bind-mount the X socket and also the `.Xauthority` file.  You also need to not be running Docker Desktop.  (Just running `./cmd/server/server` without Docker is probably vastly easier.)

Comment: Yes, I can run `./cmd/server/server` locally just fine. I need my application to be accessible across different platforms, hence Docker. I did try the solutions in that post, but the same error pops up.

Comment: The X Window System setup is fairly specific to Linux hosts; it's very unusual to have an X server at all on a MacOS or Windows system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge X11 forwarding does not expose the OpenGL driver necessary to run a Fyne application. This is similar to the open issue that a Fyne app cannot be launched from headless Linux.