# Run pyautogui script inside a docker container to control the host screen

Tags: python, linux, docker, x11, pyautogui

At work we are using docker container to run our script on a custom made Linux machine, with a touch screen display. I'm the QA there and I want to create some automation tests, that should perform virtual touch clicks.

My problem is, that the Linux machine has only basic packages and installing new ones is really tricky. Also to not mess around with the os itself, I want to use my automation script inside a docker container too. That would also give me the opportunity to test around with different packages.

I want to use `pyautogui` to simulate inputs on the touch screen (I am aware that there is a reason why that is not so easy as it sounds). At the moment, I stuck at getting the docker container get access to the screen. When I ran a simple test script I get these two error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    s.connect('/tmp/.X11-unix/X%d' % dno)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

```
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

So I know that the problem lies in the restriction with X11. I was trying out different solution I found online, but none of them worked. My next step would be to learn more about `X11` and how it works, but that could take some time.

Maybe some of you have a solution or a better way to do this. Also I'm apologizing if I confused some names related to these topic.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as notebook

WORKDIR /automation_test
COPY /src /automation_test/src

RUN apt update && apt-get update
RUN apt -y install python3 python3-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r src/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get -y install -y wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \ 
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
RUN apt-get -y install x11-apps
RUN apt-get -y install xauth
RUN apt-get -y install openbox
RUN mkdir /root/.Xauthority
RUN HOST=cctv
RUN DISPLAY_NUMBER=$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d: -f2)
RUN AUTH_COOKIE=$(xauth list | grep "$(hostname)/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} " | awk '{print $3}')
RUN xauth add ${HOST}/unix: ${DISPLAY_NUMBER} MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ${AUTH_COOKIE}
...
```

and my `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

```
version: '3.6'

x-base: &base
    ipc: host
    pid: host
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./src/results:/automation_test/src/results
      - ./src/tmp:/automation_test/src/tmp
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"


services:

  notebook:
    <<: *base
    image: notebook
    container_name: notebook
    build: 
      context: .
      target: notebook
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
```

`Disclaimer:` Most of that stuff in these files are solution I tried out, but did not work. So that is the reason it looks kinda ugly and messy. And I was using a Ubuntu base image for the moment. In the future I would like to only use a python image as as base.

Comment: A Docker container by design is an isolated environment and it can't normally interact with the host display at all.  Your Dockerfile includes a couple of `RUN` commands to try to extract the host display information, but these won't work in a Dockerfile, since `RUN` commands also happen inside containers.  Most of the setup you need happens at runtime, not image build time; does [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) have enough details for you?

Comment: The guest controlling the host sounds like an ... unusual arrangement. I'm sure many things would be easier if you could run a clone of the system you want to test in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I have to correct myself. The packages I was mentioning here were not really helpful either. But I found a really interesting package called [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I'm surprised I was not finding this earlier and not so many websites mentioned it. It's a bit much to understand, because the documentation is a bit crude, but it works like a charm, for what I want to do.

**Original:**

So I came to the conclusion, that this project of mine is too complicated to solve for now. I also noticed that, it would not work in the first place, because the linux machine, on which I wanted to run the repository, does not even have `X11` (could have checked that in the first place honestly).

A coworker actually gave me a better approach to this topic. He found [this repository](https://github.com/tio/input-emulator) which is working directly with the kernel itself and [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/).

I think this is a much better solution than trying to get X11 running in a docker.

Anyway, thanks for the help and your time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do x-forwarding like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir=$(mktemp -d); cd $dir

echo 'import pyautogui;pyautogui.write("Hello, World!")' > test.py 

docker build -t x-forwarding -f - . << EOF
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY test.py ./
RUN pip install pyautogui python-xlib
EOF

docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY\
    --name x-forwarding --rm x-forwarding python test.py
```

Once this works, you can integrate it in your docker-compose workflow.

Comment: I get the same results with your solution.

Comment: Have you tried to copy/paste my commands ? What's the result of `docker run ...` ?

Comment: Yes, I put your code in `init.sh` and let the file run. Came to the same result.