# Running containers with X Window

Tags: docker, x11

I have an application that utilizes `X Window` and `Xorg`.

```
FROM centos:7
RUN mkdir -p /app/
COPY /app /app/

CMD ["/app/main 1 &"]
```

Running it directly gives away:

```
docker run -it app:0.1
Cannot open display.
```

However, `exec` into container and then running it manually, or doing `docker run --rm --privileged -ti -e container=docker -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup app:0.1/usr/sbin/init` works fine.

Is there a way I can compensate this behavior in my application or script so I can run it as normal container or a pod?

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process, and it doesn't normally have access to the host's display at all.  It's fairly inconvenient to run an X-based program in a container, and mostly Linux-specific; also see [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container).  If you're trying to run a display server _and_ your application, a VM will be a better match (doubly true if you're expecting an init system).