# Forwarding GUI image from Docker container on air gapped network

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pyqt5, containers

I have a unique challenge I am trying solve.  The biggest obstacle I am facing is that I am running this container on an air gap network.  I ultimately need to forward a containerized  PyQt5 GUI from inside a docker container to a system running Windows 10 with X-Win32.  There is a local artifactory repository that I am pulling from, however we have a limited set of libraries in the repository.  One library we are missing is X-Server.  From my research, it seems if we get X-Server in the docker container, then all we have to do is map the x-server from the container to an external x-server on Linux and then run the container with the correct prompts.  However, as I stated, the RHEL8 image we are pulling into the docker container does not contain X-Server.  We have X-Server running on our bare metal RHEL8 Linux OS, but I don't know how I could transfer X-Server from my Linux OS into a docker container.  If I could manage that, that could potentially be a solution for us.  However, I am not entirely sure I need to move X-Server into the container, as it is already trying to forward the display to an external source.  Here is the docker file so far:

```
FROM docker-apl.artifactory.redacted/ee-29-rhel8:latest AS base
Copy Py_App/ Py_App/
Copy Whls/ Whls/

Copy lib/ /usr/lib

RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

RUN python3 -m pip RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pandas_Requirements/python_dateuitl-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pandas_Requirements/pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pandas_Requirements/tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pandas_Requirements/pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pillow-10.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/PyQt5_sip-12.9.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_x86_64.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/qt5_applications-5.15.2.2.2-py3-none-manlinux2014_x86_64.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/qt5_tools-5.15.2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/pyqt5_plugins-5.15.4.2.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl
RUN python3 -m pip install Whls/Pyqt_requirements/PyQt5_builder-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl

EXPOSE 6000

WORKDIR Py_App

CMD export DISPLAY=0:0; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib; export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1; export PYTHONPATH=/runner/Py_app; python3 py_App/main.py
```

When I run this I get an error message that reads qt.qpa.xcb:

```
Loaded library "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
could not connect to display 0:0
```

It looks like it is already trying to forward the display using libqxcb, but is failing to do so because I am not providing it the correct arguments.  If I can get this to work that would be ideal, because I don't have to go through the hassle of getting X-Server moved into the container.  Which, under my current conditions, is a lot harder than it seems.  In summary I would like to either (From most ideal to least ideal):

1. Get the display forwarding to Win10 running X-Win32 without having to add any additional libraries by adding the correct arguments

or

2. Get X-Server from our bare metal Linux operating system copied into the container.  I tried by simply copying the X-server file with my limited access and I got an error saying "Could not copy special file"

or

3. Get X-Server approved and uploaded into the air gap artifactory repository.  However, I don't know if this will 100% work.

If there are any other details you would like me to provide, let me know.

```
EDIT - Here are the libraries in the lib folder

libfontconfig.so.1
libfreetypoe.so.6
libGL.so.1
libGLdispatch.so.0
libGLX.so.0
libpng16.so.16
libX11.so.6
libX11-xcb.so.1
libXau.so.6
libxcb.so.1
libxcb.so.1.1.0
libxcb-composite.so.0
libxcb-composite.so.0.0.0
libxcb-damage.so.0
libxcb-damage.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dpms.so.0
libxcb-dpms.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dri2.so.0
libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dri3.so.0
libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
libxcb-glx.so.0
libscb-glx.so.0.0.0
libxcb-iccm.so.4
libxcb-images.so.0
libxcb-keysyms.so.1
libxcb-present.so.0
libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
libxcb-randr.so.0.
libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0
libxcb-render.so.0
libxcb-record.so.0.0.0
libxcb-render-util.so.0
libxcb-res.so.0
libxcb-res.so.0.0.0
libxcb-screensaver.so.0
libxcb-screensaver.so.0.0.0
libxcb-shape.so.0
libxcb-shape.so.0.0.0
libxcb-shm-so.0
libxcb-shm-so.0.0.0
libxcb-syc.so.1
libxcb-syc.so.1.0.0
libxcb-util.so.1
libxcb-util-so.1.0.0
libxcb-xf86dri.so.0
libxcb-xf86dri.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xfixes.so.0
libxcb-xfixes.so.0.0.0
lib-xinerama.so.0
lin-xinerama.so.0.0.0
libxcp-xinputs.so.0
libxcp-xinput.so.0.1.0
libxcb-xkb.so.1
libxcb-xkb.so.1.0.0
libxcb-xselinux.so.0
libxcb-xselinux.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xtest.so.0
libxcb-xtest.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xv.so.0
libxcb-xv.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xvmc.so.0
libxcb-xvmc.so.0.0.0
libXext.so.6
libxkbcommon.so.0
libxbcommon-x11.so.0
```

Comment: The X Window System has always supported running over a network transport, but unencrypted TCP isn't usually considered a good idea.  You can tunnel X over ssh; note that in this setup the X server is running on your _local_ system (with the keyboard and mouse and display) and the remote system (with the actual program) doesn't need to run it.  Setting this up can be tricky, and it isn't necessarily a programming-related problem.  A good first step would be getting it set up with remote X forwarding, but without Docker; does that setup work?

Comment: [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) discusses the local display, local application in a container setup, and goes into some details like the `.Xauthority` file you'll need to tackle.  The hard-coded `$DISPLAY` setting in your `CMD` probably isn't right for some cases, and it might be better to allow a `docker run -e DISPLAY=...` option to set it dynamically.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the reply.  I'm still trying to understand your reply, my experience with docker and Linux is limited.  To be clear, we have docker running on our Windows and Linux systems, however our objective is to get the container running on Windows.  You mentioned we could try ssh, would the ssh command happen from inside the container, or do we ssh into the container from outside?  Would this allow us to forward the display?

Comment: @DavidMaze I believe we did figure out a way to ssh into the container from X-Win32 on Windows.  However, the container itself is not running ssh, so it's not working.  We're now trying to figure out how to get ssh running inside the container.  However, your reply did get us moving in the right direction.  Thank you!