# x11 forwarding to docker image without --net=host is possible?

Tags: docker, x11

I am currently trying to set up X11 forwarding to a Docker image. However, I believe that using the --net=host option is necessary for this. My current command includes:

```
--net=host \
-it -p 34522:22 -p 34566:6006 -p 34588:8888 -p 34589:8889 \
```

My concern is that the --net=host option seems to override the port forwarding settings specified by -it -p 34522:22 -p 34566:6006 -p 34588:8888 -p 34589:8889.

Is there a way to enable X11 forwarding in Docker while maintaining these port forwarding settings? Or, alternatively, is there a method to achieve X11 forwarding without the --net=host option, using the given port mappings?

Comment: You shouldn't need host networking to access an X server, or for most other use cases.  Does [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) have the answer you need?  Of note, [this answer](/a/25280523) doesn't seem to need host networking, since it's accessing the X server through a bind-mounted Unix socket.

Comment: oh so network is like 
home(mac) -> server(ubuntu(docker(ubuntu)))