# Docker Image for displaying graphics (matplotlib, plotly)

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib, plotly-python

I'am trying to containerize my python project which is using matplotlib and plotly to display some graphics and tables.

However I'am having trouble to display those graphics... My script just runs and it wont display anything.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Update apt package lists and upgrade installed packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential python3-pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive to prevent prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install Pillow and its ImageTk module
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk

# Install tkinter for Python 3.9
RUN apt-get install -y python3-tk

# Install any needed dependencies specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

And here some of the functions I'am trying to use:

```py
def display_num_occurences(interesting_words: dict) -> None:
    """
    Display a bar plot with the occurrences of the interesting words
    """
    words = list(interesting_words.keys())
    occurrences = [interesting_words[word]['occurences'] for word in words]

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.bar(words, occurrences, color='blue')
    plt.title('Occurrences of Words')
    plt.xlabel('Words')
    plt.ylabel('Occurrences')
    plt.grid(axis='y')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(range(0, max(occurrences) + 1, 1))
    plt.show()

def display_table(interesting_words: dict) -> None:
    """
    Display a table using plotly with the data related to the interesting words
    """
    # Create the table data
    table_data = [['Word', 'Occurrences', 'Documents', 'Sentences']]
    table_data.append(list(interesting_words.keys()))
    table_data.append([interesting_words[word]['occurences'] for word in interesting_words.keys()])
    table_data.append(['\n'.join(interesting_words[word]['documents']) for word in interesting_words.keys()])
    table_data.append(['\n'.join(interesting_words[word]['sentences']) for word in interesting_words.keys()])
    
    # Create the Plotly figure
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
        header=dict(values=table_data[0],
                    fill_color='lightblue',
                    align='center'),
        cells=dict(values=table_data[1:],
                fill_color='white',
                align='left'))
    ])

    # Update layout
    fig.update_layout(
        title="Table of Word Occurrences",
        width=2000,
        height=1000,
    )

    # Show the figure
    fig.show()
```

I have tried a couple of different things but none seem to work.

Comment: Docker images don't have a desktop environment... Therefore it won't pop-up any plot windows. Jupyter notebook container is one solution. Or Streamlit

Comment: What have you tried?  When you say it doesn't work, what does happen?  Have you read through related question like [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container)  (Technically you can, but it's complex and specific to Linux host environments.)