# Alternatives to ssh X11-forwarding for Docker containers

Tags: user-interface, docker

I am running a Docker container mainly as an isolated development environment for the `R` language. (The usage of `R` here is orthogonal to the rest of the post, i.e. you can just assume any generic program that can run in a `repl`-session.) A lot of times this will involve doing stuff like plotting, making graphics and so on; and I need to look at 
these. Hence, I would prefer to have the option of displaying graphics I created in my container. Here is how I do this so far. First I create a `Dockerfile`. Leaving out the trivial steps the ones most relevant are:

```
# Set root passwd 
RUN echo "root:test" | chpasswd

# Add user so that container does not run as root 
RUN useradd -m docker 
RUN echo "docker:test" | chpasswd 
RUN usermod -s /bin/bash docker 
RUN usermod -aG sudo docker 
ENV HOME /home/docker

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd 
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

# copy servisord.conf which lists the processes to be spawned once this 
# container is started (currently only one: sshd) 
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 22 
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I build the image and then start the container by using:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:22 -h ubuntu-r -v /home/chb/files/Data:/home/docker/Data -P --name="rdev" ubuntu-r
```

and can then ssh into my container:

```
ssh -X docker@localhost -p 5000.
```

This will give me what I want. But I would like to know if there is another more resource friendly way of getting graphics/GUI output from a container? (I'd prefer, if possible, solutions would not involve `vnc`.)

Comment: you should have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container/28971413

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you run GUI apps in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: Related: [How to make Xvfb display visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12050021/55075) & [Using VNCserver + GUI app + Virtual Display in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36221215/55075).

Comment: `ssh -X docker@localhost -p 5000` asks for a password. As I have tried "tcuser" does not work

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is a nice and semi-easy way of getting graphical output from a
Docker container without having to run an `sshd` daemon inside of the
container. Docker can provide bare metal performance when running a single
process which in this case is supposed to be `R`. Running an sshd daemon
will, marginal as it may be, introduce additional overhead. This is not
made better by running the sshd daemon as a child process of the
supervisor daemon.  Both can be dispensed with when one makes good use of
bind mounts. After building the image from which the container is supposed
to be run we start an interactive container and bind mount the
`/tmp/.X11-unix` folder into it. I will state the complete command and
explain in detail what it does:

> docker run -i -t --rm \

- `-i` sets up an interactive session; `-t` allocates a pseudo tty; `--rm` makes this container ephemeral

> -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \

- sets the host display to the local machines display (which will usually be `:0`)

> -u docker \

- `-u` specify the process should be run by a user (here `docker`) and not by root. This step is important (v.i.)!

> -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro \

- `-v` bind mounts the `X11` socket residing in `/tmp/.X11-unix` on your local machine into `/tmp/.X11-unix` in the container and `:ro` makes the socket read only.

> --name="rdev" ubuntu-r R

- `--name=""` specify the name of the container (here `rdev`); the image you want to run the container from (here `ubuntu-r`); the process you want to run in the container (here `R`). (The last step of specifying a process is  only necessary if you have not set a default `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` for your image.)

After issuing this command you should be looking at the beautiful `R`
start output. If you were to try `demo(graphics)` to see if graphical
output is already working you would note that it is not. That is because
of the `Xsecurity` extension preventing you from accessing the socket. You
could now type `xhost +` on your local machine and try `demo(graphics)` in
your container again. You should now have graphical output. This method
however, is strongly discouraged as you allow access to your xsocket to
any remote host you're currently connected to. As long as you're only
interacting with single-user systems this might be somehow justifiable but
as soon as there are multiple users involved this will be absolutely
unsafe! Hence, you should use a less dangerous method. A good way is to
use the server interpreted

```
xhost +si:localuser:username
```

which can be used to specify a single local user (see `man xhost`). This means
`username` should be the name of the user which runs the `X11` server on
your local machine and which runs the docker container. This is also the
reason why it is important that you specify a user when running your
container. Last but not least there is always the more complex solution of
using `xauth` and `.Xauthority` files to grant access to the `X11` socket
(see `man xauth`). This however will also involve a little more knowledge
how `X` works.

The positive effect this can have can be seen in the number of processes
that need to be run in order to achieve what is wanted.

(1) with `supervisor` and `sshd` running in the container:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                4564                718                 1                18:16               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root                4576                4564                0                18:16               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/sshd
```

when logged in via `ssh` and running `R`:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                 STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                4564                718                 0                 18:16               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root                4576                4564                0                 18:16               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/sshd
root                4674                4576                0                 18:17               ?                   00:00:00            sshd: docker [priv]   
chb                 4725                4674                0                 18:18               ?                   00:00:00            sshd: docker@pts/0
chb                 4728                4725                1                 18:18               pts/0               00:00:00            -bash
```

(2) with bind mount method:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                 STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
chb                 4356                718                 0                 18:12               pts/4               00:00:00            /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R --no-save --no-restore
```

Comment: Great stuff, thank you :-) How does your solution compare to that one: http://olivier.barais.fr/blog/posts/2014.08.26/Eclipse_in_docker_container.html
(different xhost command, no -u option)

Comment: Thanks. :) In short: She/he is granting access only to a specific trusted docker container by using the containers hostname. I on the other hand grant access to a trusted user and thereby all containers she/he is starting. This works because the uid in the container is identical to the one on the host.

Comment: Ok, I get it, cheers =) If I run multiple containers, then it might be more convenient to trust the user. But I'm guessing it's also less secure. What about the -u option? You solution seems to work without it; am I missing something?

Comment: This has two(?) reasons: (1) The `-u` option just adds another layer of security. The docker daemon for now runs as root on the host. So should a process in a container escape to the host it can do a lot of damage. This is somehow migitated if the processes in the container run as a user process. (2) Granting root access to the x-socket is not a good idea. To phrase it differently: The principle of least privilege should be applied.

Comment: This does not appear to be a copy and pasteable answer. The `-u` command gives a "Error response from daemon: Cannot start container X: [8] System error: Unable to find user docker"
 error. This is despite my current running user being 'docker' and there also being a 'docker' user defined in the Dockerfile.

Comment: as the mount point /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro is linux dependent this will only work when running this container on a linux machine, correct? Is there an equivalent work around for a docker that needs to be run on linux, windows, and mac?

Comment: I run 
docker run -it --net=host --rm \
       -e DISPLAY \
       --volume=$HOME/.Xauthority:$HOME/.Xauthority \
       --privileged \
       -v $XSOCK -v $XAUTH \
       image_name

and on running xeyes in the container I get:

No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0

Answer (score 4):

Here is clearly the best solution I found until now:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280523/1353930 (all credit goes to Jürgen Weigert)

Advantages:

- Inside docker, the UID is not relevant (but I still recommend to *not* use root)
- On the host, you don't have to change security settings (`xhost +`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on lord.garbage's answer we can forward the host's X11 socket. And similarly we can create a user at docker image creation time as per Jürgen Weigert's very nice idea shared above (thanks Hugo/Daniel.) However, what if we don't want to modify xhost ACL or create an image that is statically bound to one user's credentials? There is one additional refinement that we can make:

When running your container forward user-id/group from host shell:

```
XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
docker run -it --rm \
    -e HOST_USER=$(id -u) \
    -e HOST_GROUP=$(id -g) \
    -e HOST_USER_NAME=$(whoami) \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK \
    my_container:latest
```

Create wrapper script and set it as your container's ENTRYPOINT. In your script create a new user with the host's user-id/group-id then use sudo to run your target application "as host":

```
groupadd -o -g $HOST_GROUP docker
useradd -d /home/$HOST_USER_NAME -s /bin/bash -u $HOST_USER -g docker $HOST_USER_NAME
sudo -u $HOST_USER_NAME bash -c "<some bash commands etc.>"
```

Since program will execute with correct user, access control changes are unnecessary. Thanks to Jürgen Weigert's great idea, and this small refinement we have a solution that doesn't require xhost and will run anywhere.